# Random number generation, without built-in random number generation libraries

Tags: code-golf, number, random

**Task:**

Make a random number generator. The catch is that you can't use *any* built-in randomness functions. Your random numbers must be anything between 0 and 100, though they do not have to be floating point.

**Rules:**

- It must produce a pseudorandom number.
- Randomness defined: If you run it `x` times, then `x` times again, the two sequences will be unlikely to be identical. Where 2 < x < 10.
- It is **not** required that your random number generator passes any specific test about the quality of the generated numbers, as long as the previous rule is respected.
- Any language is accepted, except Golfscript, [see here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/286/j-and-golfscript-suck-all-the-enjoyment-out-of-code-golf).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
- You may not hard-code the output numbers or read them from a file.
- Post 5 numbers generated by your program.
- Good luck!

Comment: Because I was typing the moment you commented: -1 because of arbitrarily restricting the languages accepted.

Comment: I would recommend you give an objective definition of "random". Is pseudorandom enough? Or does it have to be true random? In the latter case, how do you test it? (E.g. Diehard tests? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests )

Comment: Moreover it seems to be a duplicate (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10553/1490).

Comment: @ace there's no random generator. The only truly random one that you could have would be based probably on some quantum mechanics, but are you sure you're able to make the two measurements ortogonal? Anything software-based will be pseudo-random, since it's proved that for every PRG there exists a statistical tests that distinguishes it from a random sequence.

Comment: What about guids?

Comment: @Howard - first off, see the link next to the language restriction, and second of all, that question does not restrict the use of built-in functions

Comment: I know the link but that doesn't change my view that a question should not restrict the languages. And the other question reads *Build a random number generator* which clearly excludes built-in generators.

Comment: @microbian you mean the stuff where you shake your mouse? That doesn't fall into the "algorithmic PRG" category, that's true. However, nothing based on human action is quite considered random. (More a philosophical than mathematical question, let's rather avoid this discussion. However, as long as there's _any_ pattern in the human's behaviour and any pattern in the receptors precision, it can be somehow measured.)

Comment: @tohecz what I'm trying to say is that this question is opinion-based as the definition of "random" is open to debate. Oh and TheDoctor, here's a quote from that question: "This function must not call upon any libraries or other functions that were not also written as part of the program, especially calls to /dev/random or a language's built-in rand() library. More specifically, you are limited to the basic operators of the language you are working in, such as arithmetic, array access, and conditional flow control statements."

Comment: @tohecz, actually my comment about guids was for the OP.  Totally agree with you.

Comment: @microbian ok good to know :)

Comment: This question does not requires that the random number generators passes any diehard tests, and without this requirement, it is possible to use a different strategy to golf it. Further, the output range is distinct. This way, an answer that was invalid in the old question could be the winner here. So, it does not seems to be a duplicate for me, even if it is a very similar question.

Comment: @Victor A major problem will be, how random is "random"? Without an objective way of defining it, this should be closed as "opinion-based", and with an objective way of defining it, in my opinion this would be a duplicate.

Comment: @TheDoctor. I suggest that you edit the question with something like this: "NOTE: The program is *random enough* if it is able to output different numbers when runned multiple times and may generate any integer number in the interval 0 to 100".

Comment: Did we get an answer on GUIDs? Does that count as "built-in randomness function"? (I lean toward yes, myself.)

Comment: @microbian - yes, you can use GUIDs

Comment: @Victor that's not true. Most pseudo-random generators included in language libraries are not "able to output different numbers when ran multiple times", unless you call a specific function, usually called Randomize(), passing it an external value.

Comment: @Tobia I know, but this is not the point. My suggestion was solely with the purpose of fixing the text in the question, not to define exactly what is or what is not a pseudo-random generator. The program when runned should be able to generate any number from 0 to 100. If you do have a better suggestion, drop it here.

Comment: -1 for forbidding golfscript, per my "tradition" of sorts of downvoting these sorts of restrictions.

Comment: @thedoctor If you're going to disallow GolfScript, disallow J and APL. I worked around it with mine in allowing the function declaration to not be counted. Nothing like seeing APL not too far ahead of the pack because `String foo()` is no longer counted.

Comment: @TheDoctor I edited your question to add a rule (and hopefully reopen your question). Tell me if you are ok with it.

Comment: @Victor - that seems somewhat contradictory to the bullet right above it. It would also open up a vulnerability to answers like `return 4`

Comment: @TheDoctor What about it now?

Comment: @Victor - yep that works. Now we need 1 more reopen vote...

Comment: That's a really rubbish (not to mention ambiguous) definition of *random*.

Answer (score 5):

**C (46)**

The stack pointer is sort of a random number

```
main(x){printf("%d",((unsigned char)&x)%100);}
```

Numbers I got:

```
20
40
4
52
36
```

Comment: The question requires the numbers to be between 0 and 100. Also, please include the language and the character count in your answer. By the way, this can be golfed down a lot more. You can remove `<stdio.h>`, and remove the type definition of `main`. Here's a completely golfed down version: `main(x){printf("%d",&x);}`

Comment: Are these the rules of the game? I don't think the compiler will like that

Comment: tested on gcc and it works perfectly, as long as you ignore the warnings (warnings are not errors, and the program is still valid). In C, if no type is specified, the compiler assumes `int`. Also, by defining `x` as an argument of `main`, you save yourself a semicolon. I'm just trying to help though, if you don't want to change, it's perfectly fine with me, but please add your language to your answer!

Comment: No parens around `(unsigned char)&x` needed, `(typecast)` binds tighter than `%`

Comment: On my mac, this produces the same output with every run.

Comment: @blabla999 I guess there is some re-usage of the stack, for me works perfectly on windows

Comment: probably has to do with address randomization of new OSs

Comment: This can be golfed down further: `abs(&x)` can be used instead of the `unsigned char` typecast, and even if you want to do a typecast, an `unsigned int` will be shorter than an `unsigned char`. I'm just posting these tips hoping that they can be useful in your next code golf challenge :)

Answer (score 4):

## python, 49

```
x=7
def r(x):print(x%100);return(69069*x+1)%2**32
```

This is my first time golfing, I think this is within the rules but I'm not sure. This is a simple linear congruential generator, with starting x value as seed. User time is not used. To use, type `x=r(x)`.

Here are the results:

```
7
84
25
62
47
```

Answer (score 3):

## Linux utils and ALSA, 41

Not a winner, but possibly a more accurate source of random noise than the current time:

```
arecord -qfS32|od -l -j48 -N8|cut -c27-28
```

Sample 5 random numbers:

> 32 53 81 83 26

Comment: Unless you have no ALSA...

Comment: @TheDoctor If you have no ALSA, you better update your kernel to a non-ancient version

Comment: Oh, i have ALSA

Answer (score 2):

### Java - <s>250</s> 249 characters

```java
import java.awt.*;class A{public static void main(String[]y)throws Exception{int z=200,u=z*z-1,n=7;java.awt.image.BufferedImage b=new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(z,z));while(u>0)n^=b.getRGB(u/z,u--%z);System.out.println((n>>>1)%101);}}
```

It uses the topright 200x200 pixels of the screen as a source of randomness. The result is an integer between 0 and 100.

I runned it 5 times (this last version) and got this:

```
97
84
38
40
65
```

I had to move my windows around between each run.

Needless to say, it is a very poor random-generator:

- It is frequently predictable.
- It is easily stalled to keep giving always the same output.
- It is unlikely to produce each number between 0 and 100 with an equal probability.

So, this should not be used by any serious purpose.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7 - 82 bytes

```python
import timeit
print timeit.Timer('for i in range(1000):i**i').timeit(1)*10000%100
```

This can definitely be golfed down more. I couldn't get `timeit` working when using `from timeit import*` but I think I only lost one character there. This is my first time using the module so I'm probably missing a lot of stuff that could save characters.

Times how long it takes in (seconds?) to calculate `i**i` for 0-999, multiplies that by 10000 and takes the modulus of 100 to get the result in the correct range.

Since this works off of hardware deviation rather than a pseudorandom formula like most programs do, you could even call this "more random" than `random.random()*100`. :)

(That last part probably isn't true, but until someone explains why I'll continue to believe it.)

Comment: Last part is not true at all on machines with single running process, or in environments especially made to emulate that situation.

Comment: Dang, I felt clever for almost a whole minute. :P

Comment: In most situations, using the runtime tickcount is quite a safe seed (similar to what you do), but certainly not in the system's kernel, since the risk of reoccurance of the same seed is more than high.

Answer (score 1):

### Java - 206 characters

```java
class V{public static void main(String[]y)throws Exception{java.io.InputStream o=new java.net.URL("http://bit.ly/1gxstDI").openStream();int x,n=7;while((x=o.read())>0)n^=x;System.out.println((n>>>1)%101);}}
```

Similar to my previous answer. However, it is smaller and has some better randomness properties (but still bad). It fetches random data from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:random as a seed (I am borrowing this idea from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16399/3755)).

Running it five times, here is the output:

```
25
15
93
32
9
```

Comment: An argument could be made that you are using a built in of some other language is issuing.

Answer (score 1):

## bash, 17

```
date +%N|tail -c3
```

Outputs the last two digits of a nanosecond timestamp.

#### Sample output

```
$ ./random
24
$ ./random
52
$ ./random
82
$ ./random
69
$ ./random
72
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 9 chars

```
101|+/⎕TS
```

Nothing new. It sums the components of the TimeStamp vector (current year, month… down to ms) and takes the remainder mod 101.

Answer (score 0):

## bash — <del>108</del> 106 bytes

```
ls -al|tee -a X|grep -o [0-9]|xargs -n3|sed 's/ //g'|sort -u|awk 'BEGIN{X=0}{X=xor(X,$0)}END{print X%101}'
```

Gets a set of all three-digit triplets from a detailed listing, exclusive ORs them with each other, then prints a result modulus 101 to get [0, 100].

Depending on the activity in the directory, may be random-ish, or dynamic but predictable, but should never be static. Running it 1000 times, I was surprised that there didn't seem to be any patterns.

Sample output:

```
$ ls -al|tee -a X|grep -o [0-9]|xargs -n3|sed 's/ //g'|sort -u|awk 'BEGIN{X=0}{X=xor(X,$0)}END{print X%101}'
37
$ ls -al|tee -a X|grep -o [0-9]|xargs -n3|sed 's/ //g'|sort -u|awk 'BEGIN{X=0}{X=xor(X,$0)}END{print X%101}'
95
$ ls -al|tee -a X|grep -o [0-9]|xargs -n3|sed 's/ //g'|sort -u|awk 'BEGIN{X=0}{X=xor(X,$0)}END{print X%101}'
62
$ ls -al|tee -a X|grep -o [0-9]|xargs -n3|sed 's/ //g'|sort -u|awk 'BEGIN{X=0}{X=xor(X,$0)}END{print X%101}'
6
$ ls -al|tee -a X|grep -o [0-9]|xargs -n3|sed 's/ //g'|sort -u|awk 'BEGIN{X=0}{X=xor(X,$0)}END{print X%101}'
51
```

Comment: The question asks for 5 generated numbers. So run it one more time.

Comment: @Victor - done.

Comment: Use "sort -u" instead of "sort|uniq" to save 4 bytes

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 17

Seems like predictability isn't so much of an issue here, so here's a simple one:

```
print time**3%101
```

Five outputs:

```
59
38
17
14
94
```

I hope this answer highlights the importance of objectively defining the question.

Comment: You could drop the `**3` and shave 3 bytes off. It won't change the distribution or the predictability of your "RNG"

Comment: @Tobia I'm not really into the challenge, I just want to show by example that this question is really very poorly defined

Comment: Yes, well, depending on the circumstances, using the time of the day as a pseudo-random number can be perfectly acceptable. For example, to initialise Randomize() at the start of one's program. (Assuming an "attacker", for any definition of the term, cannot control the time of the day when your program is started or restarted.)

Comment: @Tobia I am aware of this usage. But at least those algorithms will be difficult to predict.

Answer (score 0):

**PowerShell (66)**

```
[Convert]::ToInt32((""+([guid]::newguid())).SubString(0,2),16)%100
```

5 outputs:

```
10
92
13
84
0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Ruby, 69

```
def r()(Time.now.to_f.to_s+$$.to_s+$-I.join).bytes.reduce(:+)%100;end
```

[Online Version](http://ideone.com/ZgkbBW) for testing. Uses the current time in ms, the process id ($$) and the runtime environment ($-I) for creating a pseudo-random number.

Output:

```
47
44
39
43
88
```

Comment: Run it five times and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 99 chars

```
class b{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.println(System.nanoTime()/a.hashCode()%99);}}

75
28
34
88
16
```

If you want to be really really cheap:

**java 88 Chars**

```
class b{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.println(System.nanoTime()/9%99);}}

99
86
61
15
19
```

Comment: Run each one five times and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk, 39

not a production quality random generator:

```
OperatingSystem getMicrosecondTime\\101
```

but as I generated those 5 values by eval'ing them interactively, it's me who makes it random.

Output of 5 evaluations:

```
 93 28 25 6 25
```

PS: the free running us timer is normally used for profiling...

A *much* better random gen would be:

```
'/dev/random' asFilename readStream nextByte/2.55
```

Comment: The latter is only available on *nix systems, and is a built-in (not to Smalltalk, but the OS)

Answer (score 0):

### CMD / Batch - 14 Bytes

```
echo %time:~9%
```

Grabs milliseconds off the end of the variable `%time%`.

Add `@` before the command to make it only output the number.

```
C:\>echo %time:~9%
40

C:\>echo %time:~9%
53

C:\>echo %time:~9%
19

C:\>echo %time:~9%
73

C:\>echo %time:~9%
25
```

Comment: Any output? Run it 5 times and post

Comment: @TheDoctor please see my updated answer.