# The Ideal Question

Tags: code-golf, math, number

What makes the ideal question? Perhaps it is merely the abstraction of a profound thought and the initialization of a dream, a hope, a thought, a (… *5,024.2 characters omitted*). Therefore, I propose that we find such a factor to quantify questions. I propose also that this factor be called ***Q***<sub>*F*</sub>, or the Q-factor. I determine a question's Q-factor as thus:

[image]

(Recall that [image].)

**Objective** Given a number [image] as input, determine the respective question's Q-factor on PPCG.SE. If the question does not exist, simply output `;-;` (the crying emote).

Take, for example, [image]. ([this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16327)):

The net votes, in this case, means [image].

```
views     = 23435
net votes = 33
edits     = 6
answers   = 30, answers^2 = 900
comments  = 19
charsIOPN = "Joe Z.".length = 6
```

So:

```
r_F = 6 / 6 = 1
Q_F = r_F * (23435 * 33 + 6) / (900 - 19)
    =  1  *      773361      /    881
    ~ 877.821793
```

Please provide at least 2 significant figures on ***Q***<sub>*F*</sub>.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

---

Note: Please include three examples of your program running, one of which must be this question. The other two are yours to decide. (This is just a confirmation check.) Also report the time at which you entered the query.

Comment: Programs only or are functions okay?

Comment: @AlexA. Either is fine. And look at my rep! :D It's a _**rep**_ digit! (It's 888, in case someone upvotes.)

Comment: It may be of interest to note that the SE API does not expose the number of edits on a post.

Comment: Alex makes a good point about the edits. It might require just as much code to get the number of edits as all the other stats combined since there's no quick way to use the API for it. Also, can url shorteners be used?

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies What do you suggest, then? Yes, URL shorteners can be used.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Comments make it a more valuable question- they make the denominator smaller.

Comment: While I might not know what the question is, I'm pretty sure the answer is 42.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Julia, <s>411</s> <s>382</s> <s>367</s> <s>355</s> 353 bytes

It's quite long but I'm very pleased that it works!

```julia
using Requests
n->(R(t)=readall(get(t));G(t)=JSON.parse(R("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/$t?site=codegolf"))["items"];j=G(n)[1];d=parse(Int,match(r"<span \S+n (\d+)",R("http://codegolf.xyz/posts/$n/revisions")).captures[1]);d/length(j["owner"]["display_name"])*(j["view_count"]*j["score"]+d)/(j["answer_count"]^2-length(G("$n/comments"))))
```

This creates an unnamed function that takes an integer as input and returns a float.

It requires the `Requests` package, which can be installed using `Pkg.add("Requests")`. That package provides methods for `Base.get()` for submitting HTTP requests. It also imports the `JSON` package (on which it depends, so that doesn't need to be installed separately) which we use to parse the JSON output in the response.

Ungolfed:

```julia
using Requests

function f(n::Int)
    # Define a function to submit an HTTP request and read
    # the response, returning a string
    R(t) = readall(get(t))

    # Define a function that submits a request, reads all text
    # as JSON, parses it, and extracts the items field
    G(t) = begin
        api = "http://api.stackexchange.com/questions"
        JSON.parse(R("$api/$t?site=codegolf"))["items"]
    end

    # Get the data for the question using the API
    j = G(n)[1]

    # Scrape the number of edits from the revision history HTML
    # using minxomat's handy shortened PPCG URL
    h = R("http://codegolf.xyz/posts/$n/revisions")
    d = parse(Int, match(r"<span \S+n (\d+)", h).captures[1])

    # Compute the coefficient r_F
    r = d / length(j["owner"]["display_name"])

    # Compute the Q-factor
    Q = r * (j["view_count"] * j["score"] + d) /
        (j["answer_count"]^2 - length(G("$n/comments")))

    return Q
end
```

Thanks to Dennis and Martin Büttner for golfing help!

Comment: Nice! Any place I can test this?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ For best results I recommend installing Julia 0.4.0 (currently the latest release) on your machine and running it locally. You can give the lambda a name like `f=n->...` and submit `f(16327)` at the REPL or `println(f(16327))` if you're running it from a `.jl` file. It works on [JuliaBox](https://www.juliabox.org) (requires a Google account) with Julia 0.4.0-rc2 but gives warnings when precompiling the `Requests` module.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 10, 381 bytes

```````
f=(a=StringTemplate["http://api.stackexchange.com/``````?site=codegolf"];j=Import[a["questions/",#,""],"JSON"];c=Import[a["questions/",#,"/comments"],"JSON"];r=Import[a["posts/",#,"/revisions"],"JSON"];N[#5/#6*(#1*#2+#5)/(#3^2-#4)]&@@j[[3,2,1,{5,2,12},2]]~Join~{Length@c[[3,2]],Length@DeleteCases[r[[3,2]],_?(("revision_type"/.#)=="vote_based"&)],StringLength@j[[3,2,1,3,2,6,2]]})&
```````

Just three API queries and a lot of indexing, really. Hardest part was trying to understand how to get `edits` from the available `revisions`, hopefully I got it right.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Mathematica 9. It says the `StringTemplate` argument is invalid, prints a bunch of errors, and doesn't return a result.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the version number into the title. Fixed!

Comment: So it depends on features unique to Mathematica 10?

Comment: You don't have `StringTemplate` before 10, as far as I know. You can replace that part with `a=Function["http://api.stackexchange.com/"<>#1<>ToString[#2]<>#3<>"?site=codegolf"];` and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 392 Bytes

Well, I gave it a shot.

```
from requests import*;from re import*;l=len
def i(n):
 try:s,r="http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/%s?site=codegolf","http://codegolf.xyz/posts/%i/revisions"%n;q,c=s%n,s%('%i/comments'%n);i=get(q).json()['items'][0];m=float(l(findall("<span \S+n (\d+)",get(r).text)));r=m/l(i["owner"]["display_name"]);print r*(i["view_count"]*i["score"]+m)/(i["answer_count"]**2-m)
 except:print';-;'
```

Very similar logic to Alex's [Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60586/34315). I'd like to loop through this to see which question is the most ideal but I'd rather not continually call the api for hours on end.

Comment: Requests is a third-party package. Since when were those allowed.

Comment: @ppperry Since always unless explicitly disallowed by the OP. Using external resources that exactly solve the challenge is forbidden by default but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, <s>459</s> 457 bytes

Pretty much like the rest of the answers.

```java
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream
def f={n->def j,d,u={p->new JsonSlurper().parseText(new GZIPInputStream("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/$p?site=codegolf".toURL().getContent()).getText()).items}
j=u(n)[0]
d=("http://codegolf.xyz/posts/$n/revisions".toURL().text=~/<span \S+n (\d+)/).getCount()
println((d/j.owner.display_name.length())*(j.view_count*j.score+d)/(j.answer_count**2-u("$n/comments").size()))}
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ!

Ungolfed:

```java
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream

def f = { n->

    def stackApi = "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2"

    // Fetch json from stackexchange rest api
    def getItems = { pathParam ->
        //Stackexchange compresses data, decompress before parsing json
        def httpData = "$stackApi/questions/$pathParam?site=codegolf".toURL().getContent()
        def deCompressedData = new GZIPInputStream(httpData).getText()
        def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(deCompressedData)
        return json.items
    }

    // Get the edit count from the html page
    def htmlPage = "http://codegolf.xyz/posts/$n/revisions".toURL()
    def editCount = (htmlPage.text=~/<span \S+n (\d+)/).getCount()

    // apply formula
    def json = getItems(n)[0]
    def r = editCount/json.owner.display_name.length()
    def Q = r * ( json.view_count * json.score + editCount) /
                (json.answer_count**2 - getItems("$n/comments").size())
    println(Q)
}

f(16327)
```