# Execute prints backwards

Tags: popularity-contest, programming-puzzle

Your task is to reverse the order in which some `prints` get executed.

---

**Specs:**
Your code will be in this form:

```
//some lines of code
/*code*/ print "Line1" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line2" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line3" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line4" /*code*/
//some lines of code
```

You will have to `print` (or `echo`, or `write`, or equivalent) those strings **from the fourth to the first.**

- You decide which lines of your program must `print` the strings, but they must be **adjacent**;
- Every line can contain only one `print`, and cannot exceed *60 bytes* in length;
- Since this is [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), be creative and avoid to write just a `goto` or a simple `for(i){if(i=4)print"Line1";if(i=3)...}`
- The most upvoted answer in 2 weeks wins this.
- Your output **MUST** be `Line4 Line3 Line2 Line1` **OR** `Line4Line3Line2Line1` **OR** `Line4\nLine3\nLine2\nLine1`(where `\n` is a newline), and it must be generated only by executing those `prints` backwards.

Happy coding!

**UPDATE:** Contest is over! Thank you all :)

Comment: Does Arabic count? : )

Comment: If you are able to meet the specs, of course :P

Comment: Wanted to quickly clarify one rule... When you say "Every like can contain only one print", do you mean one text line in the code file or one LOC/statement?

Comment: Every line of code can contain only one print

Comment: does it have to pass a code review - suitable for production code?

Comment: Not really, it just has to meet the specs.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

### Commodore 64 BASIC

```
40 print "Line 1"
30 print "Line 2"
20 print "Line 3"
10 print "Line 4"
```

Comment: I never could figure why line numbers are needed, until now.

Comment: I was going to propose, copying Character ROM ($D000) to RAM ($3000), swapping character bitmaps for "1"<->"4" and "2"<->"3", then running the program in forward order. This is cuter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't actually save/load or otherwise list the code in the order shown using the standard tools (definitely can't on Apple II anyway), all you could do would be type those lines in to the console in that order.  And if that's allowed couldn't you just use e.g. C# SendKeys library to type code in any of the answered languages in a different order with arrow keys to move around.

Answer (score 108):

### PHP

Abusing precedence... :-)

```
!print "Line1\n".
!print "Line2\n".
!print "Line3\n".
!print "Line4\n";
```

Comment: Amazing I did not know how it works, Can you please guide or give a link which describe how this works ?

Comment: In PHP, `print` may be used as an expression, as it may be in perl, the return value of which is always `1`. `!1` returns `bool(false)`, which when typed as a string returns the empty string. A more proper restriction for PHP might be to require `echo` rather than `print`; the above really is only one statement.

Comment: Well I am not aware of that php is executing print statement right to left in case of String concatenate operator.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj It's just grouped that way: `print ("Line 1". !print ("Line2". !print ("Line 3". !print "Line4")));` —
everything that's on the right of a print statement is part of it.

Comment: It seems to work in every version http://3v4l.org/dpSpK very impressive!

Comment: Took me a while to understand (Thanks @eisberg for the link!) but I get it now. While the first `print` is called first, it doesn't finish evaulating what it needs to print until the inner (lower) `print`s have already been called and fully evaluated. And the `!`s are just to hide the 1's that would print otherwise. Brilliant, @bwoebi!

Comment: Although you did break the rules, @bwoebi...There can't be spaces between "Line" and the numbers. ;)

Comment: @sfarbota Reading rules is hard. Fixed. Thank you :-)

Comment: [Your answer is great.](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIL1RE8b8bulhIqdEMrtCxptti-ol21RgpkJAVtx2eoSnFnWiNMQ)

Comment: Don't mean to be pedantic, but isn't this technically one Line of Code?

Comment: @Ruslan no, it's one statement, but four lines of code. just like multiple statements in one line are still one line of code…

Comment: @bwoebi Yep, you're right. That's some really cool code, then :)

Answer (score 77):

### C

Undefined behavior is the most exciting kind of behavior!

```
f(){}
main()
{
   f(printf("Line 1\n"), 
     printf("Line 2\n"), 
     printf("Line 3\n"), 
     printf("Line 4\n"));
}
```

Actual output may vary depending on your compiler, linker, operating system, and processor :)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how come this actually works, +1.

Comment: @svick: to support varargs, most C compilers put function arguments on the stack in reverse order (so the top item on the stack is always the 1st argument), which means they're likely to evaluate arguments in the same way. Of course, this assumes arguments *are* passed on the stack which becomes less and less the case with newer compilers.

Comment: As @GuntramBlohm said, the basic idea is that C function parameters are often (but not always) pushed onto the stack in a right-to-left order.  Since these are function calls, the functions are probably (but not necessarily) called from right-to-left as well.  All this is not defined by the C standard though, so while it happens to yield the right result in GCC 4 it's totally up to the compiler and calling convention what actually happens.

Comment: I thought C treated arglist commas as a sequence point.

Comment: @fluffy: Alas, it is the other way around: C does *not* treat arglist commas as sequence points, *unlike* other commas.

Comment: @WillihamTotland well then I know of some code that I *really* need to fix... thanks

Comment: FYI: With `gcc` and `clang` you can compile this successfully with: `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration` argument.

Comment: Use `puts("Line x")` instead of `printf("Line x\n")` to save 16 bytes (assuming this is counted as an equivalent to "print").

Answer (score 74):

## Java

Using reflection

```java
public class ReversePrint {
    public static void main(String[]a) {
        System.out.println("Line1");
        System.out.println("Line2");
        System.out.println("Line3");
        System.out.println("Line4");
    }
    static {
        try{
            Field f=String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set("Line1","Line4".toCharArray());
            f.set("Line2","Line3".toCharArray());
            f.set("Line3","Line2 ".trim().toCharArray());
            f.set("Line4","Line1 ".trim().toCharArray());
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Output:

```java
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

An explanation of why this works can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20945113/597419).

Comment: Horrible. I like it.

Comment: That needs to go inside a class.

Comment: @tbodt ya, since this wasn't a code-golf I left out the import and class. Otherwise it looks too wordy.

Comment: +1 People always are saying that java Strings are immutable. You prove that they aren't.

Comment: This is delightfully nasty, but the requirement of reverse execution is not met.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen shhhh... your not supposed to tell them that. :p

Comment: @Victor In Java, Strings **are** immutable. All over Stackoverflow, there are questions like "I thought Strings were immutable". They use reflection and it makes them seem immutable. Java's promises work like this: "If you use our things / classes in the way we intended, then we promise that our claims are correct." Reflection is not the way classes are intended to use.

Comment: @Quincunx I know. If you use reflection, native code calls, bytecode manipulation and instrumentation, calls to `sun.misc.Unsafe`, `rt.jar` tampering, and other dark-side dirty tricks, you can always screw things in really bad ways.

Comment: Reflection is like making database edits in production. You don't do it in production.

Answer (score 71):

### C (and sort-of Python)

New version, using a macro to fit the question format perfectly.
Following Quincunx's comment, I added `return` to make it nicer.

It also works in Python, but it prints in correct order.

```
#define print"\n",printf(
#define return"\n"))));}
#define def main(){0?

def main():
    print "Line 1"
    print "Line 2"
    print "Line 3"
    print "Line 4"
    return

main();
```

Original version - the two are practically the same, after macro substitution:

```
main(){
    printf("Line 1\n",
    printf("Line 2\n",
    printf("Line 3\n",
    printf("Line 4\n",
    0))));
}
```

Comment: +1 for the macro. Maybe include another one; something like `#define } 0))));` (I don't know exactly how macros work in C). That way you could just have the print statements in the main method, nothing else.

Comment: @Quincunx, you can't define `}`, but you can define `return`, which I now did. It's almost a polyglot now - the `print` syntax works in several script languages, `#define` is often a comment, but `main(){..}` doesn't work in any language I could find.

Comment: @Quincunx, and now it's really a polyglot.

Comment: how is the first two defines work without spaces? Would it make `print` to be replaced by `"\n",printf(`?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - The space is optional. It replaces as you say.

Answer (score 62):

### ES6 (using backwards mode ;)

Wow, it looks like the designers of ECMAScript had some incredible foresight when they made [backwards mode](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:backwards_mode) part of the spec:

```js
// activate backwards mode:
'use backwardsˈ; \* mode backwards in now *\
code of lines some ⧵\
\*code*\ "Line1" print \*code*\
\*code*\ "Line2" print \*code*\
\*code*\ "Line3" print \*code*\
\*code*\ "Line4" print \*code*\
code of lines some ⧵\
⁏ˈforwards useˈ // back to ˈnormal'.

// So simple! No need to do anything this complicated:
split('"').reduce((L,o,l)=>(l%2?o:'')+L,'')
```

Output (evaluation, really):

```
"Line4Line3Line2Line1"
```

Note that it's *exactly* of the form requested, with only slight backwardification to fit [the syntax of the mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Backwards_mode). Note also that this mode is only supported in recent versions of Firefox [at the moment](http://caniuse.com/use-backwards).

*Final note: Actually, there is no backwards mode. But this is still a valid script that runs in Firefox (copy the whole thing). :D*

---

#### ES6 "lax mode"

**BONUS**: Here's an updated version that doesn't use backwards mode, but uses the newly-specified "lax mode" where the JS engine will just try to guess what the code is supposed to do, regardless of adherence to any specified JS syntax (basically the antithesis of strict mode):

```js
// activate "lax" mode:
`use laxˋ; // also works: ˋuse relaxˋ, ˋuse guessingˋ, ˋuse whatevsˋ, etc.
//some lines of code
/*code*/ print "Line1" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line2" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line3" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line4" /*code*/
//some lines of code
ˋuse normalˋ; // same as ˋuse default`.

// Again, compare to inferior, illegible "traditional" ES6:
split('"').reduce((L,o,l)=>(l%2?o:'')+L,'')
```

Please note that "[lax mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)" is currently only available in Firefox >= 34. ;P

Comment: All 3 links you posted are leading to 404. Is this kind of joke?

Comment: @manatwork Yes. :] But the code still works.

Comment: lol; got behind the vodoo; you split the source on "-es and loop from second last to beginning skipping each 2nd part :P Nice way on that :) +1

Comment: Ah. I see now. The syntax highlighter was your accomplice here.

Comment: How does this work!? I notice that `\*` is NOT the start of a multi-line comment, but I don't know what it DOES do.

Comment: I see it now. Two kinds of single quote character in use here. Not familiar with the 2nd one that makes its appearance. Very tricky! I think this is the best one...

Comment: It's just a tricky use of certain homoglyphs: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02c8/index.htm and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2216/index.htm, plus a little creativity. :]

Comment: This is a combo [tag:popularity-contest] and [tag:code-trolling], no? :) I love it.

Comment: This is a phenomenal abuse of Javascript. I like it.

Comment: thanks @Eddified now it got clear for me, too :P
Nice abusal of it :P

Comment: Sneaky. Soooo sneaky....

Comment: ...
I actually believed this for a few minutes

Answer (score 60):

## C

```
main()
{
  int i = 0;
  for(; i == 0; printf("Line 1\n"))
    for(; i == 0; printf("Line 2\n"))
      for(; i == 0; printf("Line 3\n"))
        for(; i == 0; printf("Line 4\n"))
          i = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 58):

### Ruby

```
print 'Line1' unless
print 'Line2' unless
print 'Line3' unless
print 'Line4'
```

Edit: Alternatively,

```
def method_missing(meth,*)
  puts meth.to_s.sub('print'){}
end

printLine1(
printLine2(
printLine3(
printLine4)))
```

Comment: I prefer this because it has meth

Comment: Wouldn't you normaly post two answers if you had two solutions?

Comment: Wouldn't this look more `ruby`-ish with code blocks? http://pastebin.com/LDWpxKx8

Comment: @PacMani those parens don't use white space, they use White space.

Comment: @manatwork nice one! I do think `method_missing` is pretty Ruby-ish itself, though.

Comment: @TheConstructor I wasn't sure; I looked for guidelines and didn't find them. I get less reputation this way but I suppose a higher chance of winning.

Answer (score 51):

## PHP

I know, this is madness...

```php
goto d;
a: print "Line1\n"; goto end;
b: print "Line2\n"; goto a;
c: print "Line3\n"; goto b;
d: print "Line4\n"; goto c;
end: exit;
```

Comment: That noise you hear is Dijkstra spinning in his grave. :-)

Comment: Thought somebody said "be creative and avoid to write just a `goto`" ;-)

Comment: @TheConstructor The creative part is using goto *in PHP* ;)

Comment: So full of win.

Answer (score 42):

### Haskell

This is almost idiomatic Haskell, as the program now looks like a right-to-left function composition. If the function wasn't print, but something that would return a (useful) value the operator declaration would be unnecessary and the code would be something you'd see in libraries.

```
a << b = (const a =<< b)

main = putStrLn "Line1"
    << putStrLn "Line2"
    << putStrLn "Line3"
    << putStrLn "Line4"
```

Comment: tip: `(<<) = flip (>>)`

Comment: @Bergi That's another way to write it, I guess a little more elegant even. I was actually a little surprised to see the thing wasn't defined in prelude (or Control.Monad)

Comment: @shiona:Yeah, it's a surprising thing to miss. Happily, we have both operators for Applicatives: `<*` and `*>`.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis actually, the `<*` applicative operator is different than this `<<` : `a <* b` is equivalent to `do x<-a;b;return x` , i.e. it runs `a`'s effect first

Answer (score 41):

### Perl

```
use threads;

$a=threads->create(sub {sleep(5); print("Line1\n");});
$b=threads->create(sub {sleep(4); print("Line2\n");});
$c=threads->create(sub {sleep(3); print("Line3\n");});
$d=threads->create(sub {sleep(2); print("Line4\n");});

$a->join();
$b->join();
$c->join();
$d->join();
```

Comment: This is *theoretically* not guaranteed to print in exact reverse order.

Comment: @Cruncher I know, but with 1 second gaps the chances of it printing in anything other than reverse order are pretty slim.

Comment: @Gareth That's why I italicized theoretically :)

Comment: @Cruncher Isn't that what makes it so fun?

Comment: @Cruncher in the same way that *theoretically* my atoms could pass through a wall?

Comment: @cdeange but this is cs theory :)

Answer (score 38):

## HTML + CSS

```html
<p>Line 1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
<p>Line 3</p>
<p>Line 4</p>
```

CSS:

```css
body {margin-top:7em}
p + p {margin-top:-4em}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udU4X/1/).

Edit:
To conform to the rules better, here is a variant in XML, that actually uses `print`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css"?>
<root>
  <print>Line 1</print>
  <print>Line 2</print>
  <print>Line 3</print>
  <print>Line 4</print>
</root>
```

where style.css should be

```css
* {display:block; margin-top:3em}
print + print {margin-top:-3em}
```

## HTML without CSS

And for the heck of it, here's one without CSS.

```html
<table>
<tfoot><tr><td><table><tfoot><tr><td>Line 1</tr></tfoot>
<tbody><tr><td>                      Line 2</table></tfoot>
<tbody><tr><td><table><tfoot><tr><td>Line 3</tr></tfoot>
<tbody><tr><td>                      Line 4</table></tbody>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m45Y2/1/).

Comment: Can anybody explain the downvote? This does work when printing, you know.

Comment: You can also just do `p {float:right;}`

Comment: But then the results will all be on one line!

Comment: ...and that's allowed. :]

Comment: But they would also be right aligned!

Comment: ...and that's not disallowed. :D You could also wrap it in a div and add the CSS rule `div {float:left}`.

Comment: Hmmm... you really hate my solution, don't you? OK, OK, I made another one with less CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/udU4X/1/ That better? No added markup though, that wasn't necessary.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I don't dislike (and didn't downvote) your solution. Was just giving suggestions to make it a little more elegant. I guess I should also upvote it. :]

Answer (score 24):

## C++

```
#include <iostream>
#define Q(x,y) x ## y
#define P(x,y) Q(x, y)
#define print S P(s, __LINE__) =
struct S { const char *s; S(const char *s): s(s) {} ~S() { std::cout << s << std::endl; } };
int main() {
    print "Line1";
    print "Line2";
    print "Line3";
    print "Line4";
}
```

(Local variables are destroyed in reverse order of declaration.)

## C++11

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    struct S { void (*f)(); S(void (*f)()): f(f) {} ~S() { f(); } } s[] = {
        {[](){ std::cout << "Line1" << std::endl; }},
        {[](){ std::cout << "Line2" << std::endl; }},
        {[](){ std::cout << "Line3" << std::endl; }},
        {[](){ std::cout << "Line4" << std::endl; }},
    };
}
```

(Much the same, but using lambdas and an array data member instead.)

Comment: I posted a solution using `std::function`, and I was trying to get rid of it. Now I don't need because you got it!

Answer (score 22):

## Haskell

```
main = sequence_ $ reverse [
    putStr "Line1",
    putStr "Line2",
    putStr "Line3",
    putStr "Line4"]
```

Answer (score 21):

## Javascript

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Line 1");},900);
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Line 2");},800);
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Line 3");},700);
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Line 4");},600);
```

Comment: Using `1,2,3,4` as timeouts also works for me. (However, I do not know whether this behavior is standardized in ECMAScript.)

Comment: @ComFreek: `setTimeout` is standardized in HTML5/timers, not in ES. Also, it specifies a minimum timeout of 4ms :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yep, you are right, of course! [HTML Standard - Timers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) - if anyone is interested.

Comment: Run this on a slow enough machine (say, an 8086 running several other applications?) and it will fail. (By fail, I mean the order will not be reversed, since it will take >= 100ms to execute each statement.

Comment: @JeffDavis No it won't. See http://jsfiddle.net/wM5em/

Comment: @lastr2d2 Simulating a slow computer with while loops is fairly subjective, but I think this would be more like it: http://jsfiddle.net/7zbKw/1/. Note from http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers "This API does not guarantee that timers will run exactly on schedule. Delays due to CPU load, other tasks, etc, are to be expected."

Answer (score 21):

## C

Trying to make defiance of the tips in the question as creative as possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define print if (i == __LINE__) puts
static unsigned i;
int main(void) {
  while (--i) {
    print("Line 1");
    print("Line 2");
    print("Line 3");
    print("Line 4");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: nice abuse of a #define :P +1

Answer (score 15):

## BF

Assumes cell-wrapping.

```
++++[->+
----[> (line 1) .[-]<]++++
---[> (line 2) .[-]<]+++
--[> (line 3) .[-]<]++
-[> (line 4) .[-]<]+
<]
```

**Why it works**

The first and last lines compose of a loop that repeats four times (counter = `cell0`).

Inside the loop, there is a counter variable (`cell1`) that is increased every run.

Each lines checks if decreasing by four, three, two, or one equals zero. Therefore, on the first run, the counter is one and the last line is executed, on the second run, the third line is executed, etc.

The `(line 1)` shows where you should make the text that is printed. The arrows in the loops allocate `cell2` for this purpose. The `[-]` cleans out `cell2` after you use it.

Answer (score 15):

### Bash

In memory of the revered [SleepSort](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16452/11422) and [SleepAdd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16316/11422), I present to you... **SleepReverse**:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function print(){(sleep $((4-$1));echo "Line $1";)&}

print 1
print 2
print 3
print 4
```

Comment: For it to look more like the specs, use `$1` and `$2`: 
`function print(){(sleep $((4-$2));echo "$1 $2";)&}; print Line 1`

Answer (score 13):

### Java

```java
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class Print {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FutureTask<PrintStream>(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new FutureTask<PrintStream>(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            new FutureTask<PrintStream>(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                System.out.append("Line1"); }
            }, System.out.append("Line2")).run(); }
        }, System.out.append("Line3")).run(); }
    }, System.out.append("Line4")).run();
  }
}
```

It's all in the right timing... ;-)

Comment: The lines have to be adjacent.

Comment: They are no less adjacent than e.g. with http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20660/16293 nobody said they should look the same. Will remove some newline-characters ;-)

Comment: Okay, great :-)

Answer (score 13):

### Bash

Here comes the double-faced script:

```
#!/bin/bash
s=1
if [ $s -ne 0 ]; then tac $0 | bash; exit; fi
s=0
echo "Line1"
echo "Line2"
echo "Line3"
echo "Line4"
```

Comment: I never even knew `tac` existed! Haha, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

## Python 3

```
import atexit

atexit.register(print,"Line1")
atexit.register(print,"Line2")
atexit.register(print,"Line3")
atexit.register(print,"Line4")
```

Answer (score 11):

### Common Lisp № 1

It's easy to write a `ngorp` macro that executes its forms in reverse order:

```
(macrolet ((ngorp (&body ydob) `(progn ,@(reverse ydob))))
  (ngorp
   (write-line "Line 1")
   (write-line "Line 2")
   (write-line "Line 3")
   (write-line "Line 4")))
```

```
Line 4
Line 3
Line 2
Line 1
```

### Common Lisp № 2

Here's one that takes the problem very literally;  the code from the question appears in program without modification:

```
(macrolet ((execute-prints-backwards (&body body)
             `(progn 
                ,@(nreverse (mapcar (lambda (string)
                                      (list 'write-line string))
                                    (remove-if-not 'stringp body))))))
  (execute-prints-backwards

//some lines of code
/*code*/ print "Line1" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line2" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line3" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line4" /*code*/
//some lines of code

  ))
```

```
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

Answer (score 10):

## PHP

Another `eval` variant:

```
$lines=array_slice(file(__FILE__),-4); // get last 4 lines of current file
eval(implode('',array_reverse($lines)));exit; // eval lines reversed and exit
print "Line1\n";
print "Line2\n";
print "Line3\n";
print "Line4\n";
```

Comment: Slick! Nonetheless, I feel compelled to point out this is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 9):

## F#

```
let inline (?) f g x = g x; f x

(printfn "Line1%s") ?
 (printfn "Line2%s") ?
  (printfn "Line3%s") ?
   (printfn "Line4%s") ""
```

Just created a custom operator that executes functions in reverse order.

Comment: I am pretty sure (?) f(g(x)) = g(x); f(x) is calculus and not programming.

Comment: @JeffDavis: Pretty sure `(?) f g x` reads roughly as `(?)(f, g, x)`, not `f(g(x))`

Answer (score 9):

## Go (Golang)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("Line 1")
    defer fmt.Println("Line 2")
    defer fmt.Println("Line 3")
    defer fmt.Println("Line 4")
}
```

Try it out: http://play.golang.org/p/fjsJLwOFn2

Comment: I wanted to post the exact same code. Literally, byte-for-byte exactly the same.

Comment: @Art, awesome! I hope to see more Go used in Code Golf.

Comment: Probably won't happen. Go isn't really good a being compressed, they deliberately limit weird constructs so that you can't create an unreadable mess. But in this case (and maybe other popularity contests) it has a chance.

Answer (score 8):

## Python3

```
print("Line1",
print("Line2",
print("Line3",
print("Line4") or '') or '') or '')
```

Can be 6 bytes shorter by removing all spaces in last line.

Answer (score 7):

### Javascript

```
[
  "console.log('Line1')",
  "console.log('Line2')",
  "console.log('Line3')",
  "console.log('Line4')"
].reverse().forEach(function(e){eval(e)})
```

### C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> functors;
    functors.push_back([] { std::cout << "Line1"; });
    functors.push_back([] { std::cout << "Line2"; });
    functors.push_back([] { std::cout << "Line3"; });
    functors.push_back([] { std::cout << "Line4"; });
    std::reverse(functors.begin(),functors.end());
    std::for_each (functors.begin(), functors.end(), [](std::function<void()> f) {f();});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `std::reverse` and `std::for_each`, simply use `while (! functors.empty()) { functors.back()(); functors.pop_back(); }`

Answer (score 7):

**Batch**

```
echo off

call :revers ^
echo.line1 ^
echo.line2 ^
echo.line3 ^
echo.line4

:revers
if not "%2"=="" call :revers %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
%1
```

Comment: Welcome to codegolf! Nice post.

Answer (score 7):

## C#

Instead of directly calling the Run method, I'm creating a dynamic method that contains a copy of Run's IL bytecode, except that the load-string opcode operands are swapped. Which causes the new method to display the strings in reverse order.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Line 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Line 2");
            Console.WriteLine("Line 3");
            Console.WriteLine("Line 4");
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Run");
            var il = method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
            var loadStringOperands = new Stack<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < il.Length; i++)
            {
                if (il[i] == OpCodes.Ldstr.Value)
                {
                    loadStringOperands.Push(BitConverter.ToInt32(il, i + 1));
                    i += 4;
                }
            }

            var run = new DynamicMethod("Run", typeof(void), null);
            var gen = run.GetILGenerator(il.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < il.Length; i++)
            {
                if (il[i] == OpCodes.Ldstr.Value)
                {
                    var str = method.Module.ResolveString(loadStringOperands.Pop());
                    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, str);
                    i += 4;
                }
                else if (il[i] == OpCodes.Call.Value)
                {
                    var mInfo = method.Module.ResolveMethod(BitConverter.ToInt32(il, i + 1)) as MethodInfo;
                    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mInfo);
                    i += 4;
                }
                else if (il[i] == OpCodes.Ret.Value)
                {
                    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                }
            }

            run.Invoke(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python

yet another solution using `eval()`

```
a = [
"print('Line1')",
"print('Line2')",
"print('Line3')",
"print('Line4')"]

for line in reversed(a):
    eval(line)
```

it's not very complex, but easy to understand.

Comment: the only code I understand :D

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript

```
function golf() {
        /*
        console.log("Line1");
        console.log("Line2");
        console.log("Line3");
        console.log("Line4");
        */
        /\/\*(.+)\*\//.exec(golf.toString().replace(/\n/g,""))[1].split("; ").reverse().forEach(function(e){eval(e)});
    }

golf();
```

**Explanation:**
`golf.toString().replace(/\n/g,"")` returns the function's source on one line. The `/\/\*(.+)\*\//` regular expression matches the four `console.log` lines; it then separates them into an array, reverses the array, and uses `forEach` to `eval` each item in the array.

Edit: Removed the unnecessary `var r =`.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3

Misusing keyword arguments

```
print('Line1', end=
print('Line2', end=
print('Line3', end=
print('Line4'))))
```

Answer (score 4):

## Rebol

```
do reverse [
    (print "Line1")
    (print "Line2")
    (print "Line3")
    (print "Line4")
]
```

An alternative option that doesn't use paren! blocks would be like this:

```
reverse2: func [
    "Reverse series/block in groups of 2 elements (modifies & returns)"
    s [block! series!]
  ][
    forskip s 2 [insert s take/last/part s 2]
    s
]

do reverse2 [
    print "Line1"
    print "Line2"
    print "Line3"
    print "Line4"
]
```

#### A little explanation

In Rebol, code is data and data is code...

```
four-lines: [
    print "Line1"
    print "Line2"
    print "Line3"
    print "Line4"
]
```

At this point *four-lines* is just a variable pointing to data.  But we can assign it to a function like so:

```
print-4-lines: does four-lines

; or exactly same is

print-4-lines: func [] four-lines
```

Now the *print-4-lines* function will print the 4 lines as is.  However if we do this...

```
print-4-lines: does reverse2 four-lines
```

then *print-4-lines* now prints in reverse order.

If you go into Rebol console (REPL) you will see that *print-4-lines* function code is reversed.

```
>> source print-4-lines
print-4-lines: make function! [[][
    print "Line4"
    print "Line3"
    print "Line2"
    print "Line1"
]]

>> print-4-lines
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

Comment: Edit submitted as you actually don't need the COMPOSE *(since the parens are harmless in the DO evaluator in this case, unnecessary precedence grouping...)*  :-)

Comment: @Dr.Rebmu Of course!  Thats much better thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

#### XQuery

As XQuery does not have any `print` statement (for those of you not familiar with XQuery, the result is simply outputted to the user) I defined a completely useless pseudo-print function, which does exactly nothing. This is just because you guys all have this nice and shiny `print` functions and I am trying to blend in.

```
declare function local:print($o) { $o };

fold-right((
  local:print("Line 1"),
  local:print("Line 2"),
  local:print("Line 3"),
  local:print("Line 4")
  ), (),
  function ($i, $r) { $r, $i }
)
```

You could also simply use `reverse()`, but how boring would that be? Instead it takes advantages of the powerful [Higher-Order functions](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Higher-Order_Functions) feature.

Answer (score 4):

## C++

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::function<void ()> a = [](){};
    a = [=](){ std::cout << "Line 1"; a(); };
    a = [=](){ std::cout << "Line 2"; a(); };
    a = [=](){ std::cout << "Line 3"; a(); };
    a = [=](){ std::cout << "Line 4"; a(); };
    a();
}
```

Note that this would behave very differently if I used `[&]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Couldnt resist abusing overloaded System.out :P

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class A
{
    public static void main(String[] arggxes)
    {
        CStream c = new CStream(System.out);
        System.setOut(c);
        System.out.println("Line 1");
        System.out.println("Line 2");
        System.out.println("Line 3");
        System.out.println("Line 4");
        c.done();
    }

}
class CStream extends PrintStream
    {
        ArrayList<String> bfr;
        public CStream(PrintStream ul) 
        {
            super(ul);
            bfr=new ArrayList<>();
        }
        @Override
        public void println(String x)
        {
            bfr.add(x);
        }
        public void done()
        {
            for (int i = bfr.size(); i > 0; i--)
            {
                super.println(bfr.get(i-1));
            }
        }
    }
```

variable string amount print() with string as return works, too :P; inspired by the printf c one and the rebol one

```
class pr
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        print("Line1",
        print("Line2",
        print("Line3",
        print("Line4"
                ))));
    }
    public static String print(String... in)
    {
        System.out.println(in[0]);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Pseudo Code** (will probably work in most languages with minor tweaks)

```
void printLine1() { print "Line 1"; }    
void printLine2() { print "Line 2"; }    
void printLine3() { print "Line 3"; }
void printLine4() { print "Line 4"; }

main
{
   printLine4();
   printLine3();
   printLine2();
   printLine1();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Java

Using instance initializers:

```
class L1 {{new L2();System.out.println("Line 1");}}
class L2 {{new L3();System.out.println("Line 2");}}
class L3 {{new L4();System.out.println("Line 3");}}
class L4 {{System.out.println("Line 4");}}
public class S {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new L1();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice work; and someone in PHP used the exact similar way to tackle this :P
but still nice way to trololol the code order

Answer (score 4):

## Bash and coreutils

Not very creative, I'm afraid, but gets the job done with the `tac` tool, which is built for this job:

```
{
    echo "Line1"
    echo "Line2"
    echo "Line3"
    echo "Line4"
} | tac
```

Answer (score 4):

## COBOL

The original of this I wrote some 30 years ago, so if the prize was for the oldest living, if brought-back-to-life, example of such a task... I re-wrote it about three years ago. After I had posted parts of it, parts appeared on some French web-site. This is the original and full working program, which I have posted some time last year on a LinkedIn group.

It still "works" today, and would have "worked" with the first COBOL compilers. GNU Cobol is readily available (SourgeForge) for anyone who would like to test the program...

The reason for writing it is mentioned in comments. Explanation follows the code. Enjoy :-)

```
   ID DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. DEEPDOO.
  *REMARKS. THE PURPOSE OF THIS PROGRAM IS TO SHOW THAT, FAR
  *         FROM "THAT CAN'T BE THE PROBLEM, COBOL DOESN'T DO
  *         THAT", IT IS, AND IT DOES.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  A1-FG PIC X VALUE SPACE.
   01  B1-FG PIC X VALUE SPACE.
   01  C1-FG PIC X VALUE SPACE.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   OBLIGATORY-SECTION SECTION.
   OB-PARA.
       PERFORM A
       IF A1-FG EQUAL TO "Y"
           DISPLAY "DO"
           GO TO G6
       END-IF
       .
   G1.
       PERFORM B
       IF B1-FG EQUAL TO "Y"
           DISPLAY "DOO"
           GO TO G5
       END-IF
       .
   G2.
       PERFORM C
       IF C1-FG EQUAL TO "Y"
           DISPLAY "IN DEEP"
           GO TO G4
       END-IF
       .
   G3.
       GO TO C5
       .
   G4.
       GO TO B5
       .
   G5.
       GO TO A5
       .
   G6.
       MOVE +11 TO RETURN-CODE
       GOBACK
       .
   A SECTION.
   A0-PARA.
       GO TO G1
       .
   A5.
       MOVE "Y" TO A1-FG
       .
   A9.
       EXIT.
   B SECTION.
   B0-PARA.
       GO TO G2
       .
   B5.
       MOVE "Y" TO B1-FG
       .
   B9.
       EXIT.
   0A SECTION.
   0-PARA.
       DISPLAY "I WAS GOING ALONG QUIETLY AND NOW I'M"
       .
   C SECTION.
   C0-PARA.
       IF C1-FG NOT EQUAL TO "Y"
           GO TO G3
       ELSE
           GO TO C9
       END-IF
       .
   C5.
       MOVE "Y" TO C1-FG
       GO TO 0-PARA
       .
   C9.
       EXIT.
   Z-OBFUSCATION SECTION.
   Z-OB.
       DISPLAY "IT DOESN'T GET HERE, NOT IN A MILLION YEARS"
       STOP RUN.
```

There, wasn't so bad, was it?

Output is:

```
I WAS GOING ALONG QUIETLY AND NOW I'M
IN DEEP
DOO
DO
```

Which is just a different way of spelling

```
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

When COBOL was designed, it was done such that a label (a paragraph or a SECTION) could be the target of a PERFORM or a GO TO or just "fallen into" sequentially, and even, though not explicitly stated, any combination for the same label.

The problem arises when the same label is already under the scope of a PERFORM, a GO TO (accidentally) comes out of the range of the PERFORM (leaving it still "active") and control later arrives at the same label. If progress is then smoothly to the end of the scope of the original PERFORM, then control will be returned to the statement ***after the original PERFORM***, no matter what else has happened since (as long as an infinite loop has not been created).

Very, very, bad practice to knowingly make use of that. Very. Can't stress that enough. Very, very, bad.

However, carelessness in whirling chunks of code about in an editor can cause this unintentionally. It can also be deliberately coded, without realising the consequences (example on SO recently, but without causing this type of problem).

However, when it does happen, the consequences evident seem so unlikely that people do not believe it. Parts of a program appear to, and actually do, run out of their expected sequence.

Of course, the "expected sequence" is just wrong, not the actual sequence, until you know what to expect, and then everything is OK (except the program doesn't work).

After two people came to me within a week with this type of problem, and didn't believe what I told them (although that bit of their code worked after my pointing out the errant GO TOs) I wrote the program to show these and any future Doubting Thomases.

For fun I compiled it using GNU COBOL with the -debug switch, which lists each verb and label as they are encountered. Here is the output:

```
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: PERFORM                Line: 15
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Section:   A                      Line: 48
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: A0-PARA                Line: 49
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 50
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: G1                     Line: 21
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: PERFORM                Line: 22
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Section:   B                      Line: 57
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: B0-PARA                Line: 58
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 59
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: G2                     Line: 28
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: PERFORM                Line: 29
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Section:   C                      Line: 70
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: C0-PARA                Line: 71
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: IF                     Line: 72
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 73
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: G3                     Line: 35
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 36
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: C5                     Line: 78
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: MOVE                   Line: 79
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 80
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: 0-PARA                 Line: 67
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: DISPLAY                Line: 68
I WAS GOING ALONG QUIETLY AND NOW I'M
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Section:   C                      Line: 70
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: C0-PARA                Line: 71
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: IF                     Line: 72
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 75
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: C9                     Line: 82
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: EXIT                   Line: 83
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: IF                     Line: 30
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: DISPLAY                Line: 31
IN DEEP
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 32
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: G4                     Line: 38
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 39
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: B5                     Line: 61
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: MOVE                   Line: 62
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: B9                     Line: 64
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: EXIT                   Line: 65
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: IF                     Line: 23
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: DISPLAY                Line: 24
DOO
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 25
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: G5                     Line: 41
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 42
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: A5                     Line: 52
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: MOVE                   Line: 53
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: A9                     Line: 55
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: EXIT                   Line: 56
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: IF                     Line: 16
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: DISPLAY                Line: 17
DO
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GO TO                  Line: 18
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Paragraph: G6                     Line: 44
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: MOVE                   Line: 45
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Statement: GOBACK                 Line: 46
Program-Id: DEEPDOO          Exit:      DEEPDOO
```

Line: 80 is what causes the unwinding of the PERFORMs to start, as control will "fall through" from the target of that GO TO into the following SECTION.

This mimics the situation where a SECTION in the program has been copied, modified, but the "GO TO *the named paragraph which happens to be the end of the PERFORM range* has not been changed - so it GO TOs the end of the wrong SECTION, and "falls through" into the next SECTION and continues falling until it stumbles across a PERFORM-range which is still active, or it gets into a Big Fat Loop or the end of the program is reached.

There are COBOL programmers who feel it is OK to use `GO TO` to get to the last paragraph of a PERFORM-range (I'm not one). If doing this, and using SECTIONs, it is best to name the final paragraph in each SECTION identically. The compiler will then automatically "qualify" that paragraph-reference in the GO TO to being the one in the current SECTION.

Comment: Never seen such beautiful code before...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks. I've never had *this* program described as beautiful. Updated with -debug results, if interested to see it flying around...

Comment: This is absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript

```
console.log("Line 1", 
(console.log("Line 2",
(console.log("Line 3", 
(console.log("Line 4"), "")), "")
  ), "")
)
```

Answer (score 3):

### **Postscript**

```
{
    currentfile 
    60 string readline 
        { cvx }
        { pop count { exec } repeat exit } 
    ifelse 
} loop
(Line1\n) print
(Line2\n) print
(Line3\n) print
(Line4\n) print
```

and

```
gs -q -dBATCH print_backwards.ps
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

P.S. Oh, and if, I see, there should be some code *after* our `print "LineX"`, it can be modified easily:

```
4 {
    currentfile 
    60 string readline pop cvx
} repeat
(Line1\n) print
(Line2\n) print
(Line3\n) print
(Line4\n) print
count { exec } repeat
(And that's all!\n) print
```

and

```
gs -q -dBATCH print_backwards.ps
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
And that's all!
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt in **Befunge**:

```
"4"21p"3"22p"2"23p"1"24pv
" 1eniL",,,,,,   v      >
" 2eniL",,,,,,  v>
" 3eniL",,,,,, v>
" 4eniL",,,,,,@>
```

`" 1eniL",,,,,,` is a print statement; it prints `Line1`.

This works by modifying the code, overwriting the numbers in the print statements before they are executed.

Output:

```
Line4 Line3 Line2 Line1
```

However, since it unfortunately looks like that is not allowed (it is not executing the statements in reverse order, but modifying them), this works:

```
 v
" 1eniL",,,,,,@>
" 2eniL",,,,,, ^>
" 3eniL",,,,,,  ^>
" 4eniL",,,,,,   ^>
 >                ^
```

Comment: “[Your output] must be generated only by executing those prints **backwards**.” Your first solution doesn't execute anything backwards.

Comment: The first solution is not bending the rules, it's breaking them: it's clearly stated that `Your code will have this form: //some lines of code
/*code*/ print "Line1" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line2" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line3" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line4" /*code*/
//some lines of code` This means that you must code them in this order but execute them in the opposite way.

Comment: Still not good, I'm sorry. As I stated in another comment, the contest is not about printing the strings, but executing the commands in the reverse way (like the title says). You are not actually executing those last three prints since they're comments.

Comment: @Quincunx No, you are executing another `print` command that has the same arg, written before the comment. You cannot run a comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13016/discussion-between-quincunx-and-vereos)

Comment: You can easily use `,,,,,,"Line 1 "`, which is much nicer, if you execute right to left.

Comment: @ugoren Yeah, but what's the fun in that?

Answer (score 3):

**C++11** using UDL and abusing RAII.

```
#include <iostream>

class wrapper
{
public:
  const char *s_;
  wrapper(const char *s) : s_(s) {}
  ~wrapper() { std::cout << s_ << std::endl;}

};

wrapper operator "" _print(const char *str, long unsigned int)
{
  return wrapper(str);
}

int     main()
{
  wrapper test[] = {
    "Line 1"_print,
    "Line 2"_print,
    "Line 3"_print,
    "Line 4"_print,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## OCaml

Since lists are created starting from the tail prepending elements in front of it, these print statements end up executing backwards.

```
[print_string "Line1";
print_string "Line2";
print_string "Line3";
print_string "Line4"]
```

output is

```
Line4Line3Line2Line1
```

(you can try it [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_ocaml_online.php))

Answer (score 3):

**Python**

After a little setup, you can get reversed printing from nearly unaltered Python code. (You do need parens around your print arguments).

```python
from __future__ import print_function
import atexit
stack=[]
def done():
    stack.reverse()
    for a,k in stack: __builtins__.print(*a,**k)
atexit.register(done)
def print(*args,**kwargs):
    stack.append((args,kwargs))

#normal code from here down.

print('Line1')
print('Line2')
print('Line3')
print('Line4')
```

Comment: nice way :) seems that ya got inspired by my modified output stream in java :) +1

Answer (score 3):

## Bash

This one abusing [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) process substitution and redirects:

```
< <(< <(< <(< <(
1>&2 echo "Line1")
1>&2 echo "Line2")
1>&2 echo "Line3")
1>&2 echo "Line4")
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5

```perl
use 5.010;

!say "Line 1",
!say "Line 2",
!say "Line 3",
!say "Line 4";
```

This works basically the same way as [bwoebi's PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20693): the return value of each of the `say` commands is given as an argument to the previous one, so the interpreter must evaluate them from last to first.  The negation operator `!` maps the return values from `1` to an empty string, keeping them from interfering with the output.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void line1() { printf("line1\n"); }
void line2() { printf("line2\n"); }
void line3() { printf("line3\n"); }
void line4() { printf("line4\n"); }

int main() {
  atexit(line1);
  atexit(line2);
  atexit(line3);
  atexit(line4);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell

```
(<<)=flip(>>)
main=putStrLn "Line1" <<
     putStrLn "Line2" <<
     putStrLn "Line3" <<
     putStrLn "Line4"
```

Answer (score 3):

### Coldfusion

---

anything not in a coldfusion tag is written to the output webpage, Coldfusion also lets you treat pretty much any string as a list and loop over a list in an output tag where things in #'s are evaluated

```
<cfsavecontent variable="output">
    Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3
    Line 4
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset output = ListSort(output,'text','desc',chr(13))>

<cfloop index="i" list="#output#" delimiters="#chr(13)#">
    <cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.7

The great thing about dynamic languages is that you can override anything. Also, finalizers are the future.

```
import sys
class StdOut(object):
    text = ""
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
    def write(self, text):
        self.text = text + self.text
    def __del__(self):
        self.stdout.write(self.text)
sys.stdout = StdOut()

print "Line1"
print "Line2"
print "Line3"
print "Line4"
```

Note that we haven't overridden `print` - we're using the stock `print` function that comes with Python.

Answer (score 3):

## Thue

```
00::=~Line1
11::=~Line2
22::=~Line3
33::=~Line4
::=
01233210
```

Answer (score 2):

## Tcl

Inspired by [histocrat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6828/histocrat)'s [Ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20667).
Just demonstrates that any proc can be renamed and/or re-declared in Tcl.

```tcl
rename puts stup

proc puts {{arg ""}} {
  global buffer
  if {$arg == ""} {
    stup [lreverse $buffer]
  } else {
    lappend buffer $arg
  }
}

puts Line1
puts Line2
puts Line3
puts Line4
puts
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ tclsh reverseputs.tcl
Line4 Line3 Line2 Line1
```

## Tcl

Inspired by all those looping solutions.
Just demonstrates that no `eval` is needed, as everything is a string.

```tcl
foreach {line puts} [lreverse {
  puts Line1
  puts Line2
  puts Line3
  puts Line4
}] {
  $puts $line
}
```

Sample output:

```
bash-4.2$ tclsh reverseputs.tcl
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

## Tcl

Minimal version.

```tcl
puts Line1[
puts Line2[
puts Line3[
puts Line4]]]
```

Sample output:

```
bash-4.2$ tclsh reverseputs.tcl
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

Comment: My upvote was for the last one.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP

Based on a sleepsort

```
<?php
if (!pcntl_fork()) { sleep(4); echo 'Line 1'; die;}
if (!pcntl_fork()) { sleep(3); echo 'Line 2'; die;}
if (!pcntl_fork()) { sleep(2); echo 'Line 3'; die;}
if (!pcntl_fork()) { sleep(1); echo 'Line 4'; die;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new Action[] { 
            () => Console.WriteLine("Line 1"),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Line 2"),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Line 3"),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Line 4"),
        }.Reverse().ToList().ForEach(a => a.Invoke());
    }
}
```

or:

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var a in new Action[] { 
                () => Console.WriteLine("Line 1"),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Line 2"),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Line 3"),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Line 4"),
            }.Reverse())
            a.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Or:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var t = new Stack<Action>(new Action[] { 
                () => Console.WriteLine("Line 1"),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Line 2"),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Line 3"),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Line 4"),
            });
        while (t.Count > 0)
            t.Pop().Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `a.Invoke()` when you can just `a()`?

Comment: Habit I guess :P I think `Invoke()` more clearly conveys what's happening, but you are correct. However, since it's not a "shorter == better" contest I think I'll leave it this way.

Answer (score 2):

## F#

Pretty much like the Michael's JS and C++ entry.

```
[(fun () -> printfn "Line 1");
 (fun () -> printfn "Line 2");
 (fun () -> printfn "Line 3");
 (fun () -> printfn "Line 4")]
|> List.rev |> List.iter(fun u-> u())
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP

```
<?php
ob_start();print 'Line 1';$a=ob_get_clean();
ob_start();print 'Line 2';$a=ob_get_clean().$a;
ob_start();print 'Line 3';$a=ob_get_clean().$a;
ob_start();print 'Line 4';$a=ob_get_clean().$a;
fwrite(STDOUT, $a);
```

i'm not sure if it actually qualifies, as the prints are executed in order

Comment: It works but the print statements need `\n`.

Comment: @Boann where? i'm using the second output style from the specs

Comment: ‍@Einacio Oh I see. Okay.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl

```
$_->() for reverse
  sub { print "Line1\n" },
  sub { print "Line2\n" },
  sub { print "Line3\n" },
  sub { print "Line4\n" };
```

Comment: @Quincunx There's a few moving parts here but the key point is that Perl has first class functions.  Above uses a list of 4 anonymous functions (sub), it reverses this list then iterates over the list (for), this `for` usage is postfix so works on the $_->() that precedes. The `$_` is Perl's *it* (context) variable which `for` aliases to with each iteration. Finally the `->()`  runs (calls) the anonymous functions that `$_` points to.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript

Kinda wanted to avoid using eval() or strings, so I gave each Line a separate function.

.reverse() makes it still too easy. :9

```
var cg = [
  function() {console.log('Line one')},
  function() {console.log('Line two')},
  function() {console.log('Line three')},
  function() {console.log('Line four')}
];
for(i in cg.reverse()) {cg[i]()}
```

Output:

```
Line four
Line three
Line two
Line one
```

---

Guess I could replace the loop with

```
for(i in cg) {cg[cg.length-++i]()}
```

to make it more interesting. Doesn't make it prettier, though.

Answer (score 2):

## SQL

(mySQL 5.6)

```
SELECT 'Line1' UNION
SELECT 'Line2' UNION
SELECT 'Line3' UNION
SELECT 'Line4' 
ORDER BY Line1 DESC;
```

If you count SELECTing a literal as equivalent to a print statement anyway.

mySQL defaults to including the column name and adding fancy table formatting, but if you're at the cli they can be turned off if you do something like:

```
mysql --skip-column-names -B -e "SELECT 'Line1' ... etc ...;"
```

Output:

```
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#

Switching the console output to a `MemoryStream` and modifying that before dumping to screen

```
void Main()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        var defaultOut = Console.Out;

        // change the console output to the in-memory writer
        Console.SetOut(writer);

        Console.WriteLine("line1");
        Console.WriteLine("line2");
        Console.WriteLine("line3");
        Console.WriteLine("line4");

        // reset the console output to the default
        Console.SetOut(defaultOut);
    }

    // write the contents of the MemoryStream to screen whilst tweaking the output
    Console.Write(stream.ToArray().Select(SwitchChar).ToArray());
}

public char SwitchChar(byte b)
{
    var c = (char)b;
    switch (c)
    {
        case '1': return '4';
        case '2': return '3';
        case '3': return '2';
        case '4': return '1';
        default: return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 :) similar approach i used; but seems that Principle that works in mutiple languages

Answer (score 2):

Kinda lame, but I think it works. C-like languages.

```
main()
{
    switch(4)
    {
    case 1: print(1); goto 5; break;
    case 2: print(2); goto 1; break;
    case 3: print(3); goto 2; break;
    case 4: print(4); goto 3; break;
    case 5: break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Batch

```
@echo off
cls
goto d
:a
echo 'line1' & goto e
:b
echo 'line2' & goto a
:c
echo 'line3' & goto b
:d
echo 'line4' & goto c
:e
pause>nul
```

Quite frankly the best I could do...

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation)

```
1 print
2 print
3 print
4 print
```

## Output

```
4
3
2
1
```

> Print doesn't actually exist in RProgN, it's actually titled just 'p'. This just appends 1 through 4 to the stack, then RProgN implicitly prints the stack from top to bottom, which gives the desired result.

Comment: This doesn't meet the specs. You have to use your language's print.

Comment: Although it doesn't use the explicit `p`, this does use the language's print. Simply, it's Implicit one, not the Explicit one.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl

At last a use for `eval`:

```
eval(join("", reverse <<"HERE"
print "Line 1\n";
print "Line 2\n";
print "Line 3\n";
print "Line 4\n";
HERE
))
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Perl**

```
eval for reverse <DATA>
__DATA__
print "Line 1\n"
print "Line 2\n"
print "Line 3\n"
print "Line 4\n"
```

More or less an equivalent of my **Postscript** answer (though I like it less because of `reverse`. Stack-based Postscript is beautiful there, if you excuse me praising my own answer)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica

```
Unprotect[Line];
Line = "Line4";
Line i_ ^:= "Line" <> ToString[5 - i]
Print[Line 1]
Print[Line 2]
Print[Line 3]
Print[Line 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript

```
' \
    print "Line1" \
    print "Line2" \
    print "Line3" \
    print "Line4" \
'.replace(/["\s\\]/g,"").split("print").reverse().map(function(line){if(line)console.log(line)});
```

`Print()` means print(er) so outputs to console instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

Those pretty lines

```
map+$_->(),reverse
sub{print"Line1"},
sub{print"Line2"},
sub{print"Line3"},
sub{print"Line4"};
```

Comment: almost the same as http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20707

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3

```
class Printer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = []

    def print(self, text):
        self.buffer.append(text)

        if len(self.buffer) == 4:
            while self.buffer:
                print(self.buffer.pop())
```

```
printer = Printer()

printer.print('Line 1')
printer.print('Line 2')
printer.print('Line 3')
printer.print('Line 4')
```

Answer (score 1):

## K

K is evaluated right to left

```
(
  -1@"line 1";
  -1@"line 2";
  -1@"line 3";
  -1@"line 4"
  );
```

.

```
$ q a.k -q
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.SetOut(new BackwardsWriter());

        Console.WriteLine("Line 1");
        Console.WriteLine("Line 2");
        Console.WriteLine("Line 3");
        Console.WriteLine("Line 4");
    }
}

class BackwardsWriter : TextWriter
{
    private readonly TextWriter console = Console.Out;
    private readonly IList<string> lines = new List<string>();

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        lines.Add(value);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return console.Encoding; }
    }

    ~BackwardsWriter()
    {
        foreach (var line in lines.Reverse())
        {
            console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this may not actually work (objects are not required to be finalized in C#), but it does work for me in VS 2012.

Comment: You could improve this by immediately printing when the `lines` count reaches 4. Then you would not depend on finalization.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus Yeah, but then I would depend on there being exactly 4 lines, I think that goes against the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl

there is more than one way to do it!

```
package MagicHandle;
require Tie::Handle;
our @ISA = qw(Tie::Handle);
my @data = ();
sub TIEHANDLE { my $i; bless \$i, shift }
sub PRINT { shift @_; push @data, @_ }
sub UNTIE { print reverse @data }

package main;
tie *fh, 'MagicHandle'; 
select *fh;

print "one";
print "two";
print "three";
print "four";

select STDOUT; 
untie *fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

Why use `eval` when you have [data wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php)?

```
<?die(include('data:text/plaintext;base64,'.base64_encode(implode(PHP_EOL,array_slice(array_reverse(file(__FILE__)),0,4)))));?>
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

For this to work you must be running PHP 5.2 or greater and both `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` must be set to "On" in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

**Rebol**

```
do  sort/skip/reverse/compare [
  print "Line1"
  print "Line2"
  print "Line3"
  print "Line4"
] 2 2
```

and

```
cmd:  [
  [print "Line1"]
  [print "Line2"]
  [print "Line3"]
  [print "Line4"]  
]   
for i 4 1 -1 [do cmd/:i]
```

one more

```
until [
  do cmd: skip tail [
    print "Line1"
    print "Line2"
    print "Line3"
    print "Line4"
  ] -2
  empty? head clear cmd
]
```

Rebol allows so many variations on that

```
do reverse [
 "" 
 print "Line1" 
 print "Line2" 
 print "Line3" 
 print "Line4" 
 print
]
```

.

```
print also "line 1" print also "line 2" print also "line 3" print "line 4"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3.3

```python
print('Line 1') if not \
(print('Line 2') if not \
(print('Line 3') if not \
print('Line 4') else None) else None) else None
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript

Because of the nature of this problem; it is best that we use scalable asynchronous code.

```js
var config = {
    maxLines: 4,
};

print.lines = 0;
function print() {
    // Error checking
    if (++print.lines > config.maxLines) throw new Error('T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM');

    // TODO: Implement Promises
    window.setTimeout(
        console.log.apply.bind.apply(
            console.log.apply, [
                console.log,
                console,
                arguments
            ]
        ),
    config.maxLines + 4 - print.lines);
}


print('Line 1');
print('Line 2');
print('Line 3');
print('Line 4');
```

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: Hoho, knew I forgot something. Edit made

Comment: T_PAAMAYIM_NEKOTAYIM What? I don't even...

Comment: This answer is a parody, and should not be taken very seriously. @Jeff `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKOTAYIM` is poking fun at PHP's obscure error, described [here](http://phpsadness.com/sad/1).

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab: something different

```
s = {'print ' 'Line1'...
     'print ' 'Line2'...
     'print ' 'Line3'...
     'print ' 'Line4'};

[s{end:-2:2}]
```

Obfuscation attempted

Answer (score 1):

## **SQL**

I felt a little left out no one tackled this with SQL.

```
declare @oldsql varchar(max)
declare @newSQL varchar(max)
declare @findvar varchar(7)
declare @replaceVar varchar(20)
declare @varLength int
declare @sqlLength int

set @findvar = '%print%'
set @varLength = len(@findvar) - 3

set @oldsql = 
        ' print ''Line1''' + 
        ' print ''Line2''' + 
        ' print ''Line3''' + 
        ' print ''Line4''' 

set @sqlLength = len(@oldsql)

SET @newSQL = (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@oldsql 
            ,@sqlLength - PATINDEX(reverse(@findvar)
            ,REVERSE(@oldsql)) - @varLength
            ,LEN(@oldsql)))
SET @replaceVar = 
    RIGHT(@oldsql
        ,PATINDEX(reverse(@findvar)
        ,REVERSE(@oldsql))+@varLength)
SET @oldSql = 
    RTRIM(REPLACE(@oldSQL
        , REPLACE(@replaceVar,'','''')
        ,''))
SET @sqlLength = LEN(@oldsql)

SET @newSQL = @newSQL +  (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@oldsql 
            ,@sqlLength - PATINDEX(reverse(@findvar)
            ,REVERSE(@oldsql)) - @varLength
            ,LEN(@oldsql)))
SET @replaceVar = 
    RIGHT(@oldsql
        ,PATINDEX(reverse(@findvar)
        ,REVERSE(@oldsql))+@varLength)
SET @oldSql = 
    RTRIM(REPLACE(@oldSQL
        , REPLACE(@replaceVar,'','''')
        ,''))
SET @sqlLength = LEN(@oldsql)

SET @newSQL = @newSQL +  (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@oldsql 
            ,@sqlLength - PATINDEX(reverse(@findvar)
            ,REVERSE(@oldsql)) - @varLength
            ,LEN(@oldsql)))


SET @replaceVar = 
    RIGHT(@oldsql
        ,PATINDEX(reverse(@findvar)
        ,REVERSE(@oldsql))+@varLength)
SET @oldSql = 
    RTRIM(REPLACE(@oldSQL
        , REPLACE(@replaceVar,'','''')
        ,''))
SET @sqlLength = LEN(@oldsql)

SET @newSQL = @newSQL +  (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@oldsql 
            ,@sqlLength - PATINDEX(reverse(@findvar)
            ,REVERSE(@oldsql)) - @varLength
            ,LEN(@oldsql)))
exec (@newSQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Rebol

```
use [p][p: :print  print: func [s n [any-type!]][p s]]
print {Line1}
print {Line2}
print {Line3}
print {Line4}
```

Normally 'print only takes 1 argument, but we're redefining it to take 2 - the second of which is the next call to `print, which must be evaluated first to get a return value.

Except because it accepts [any-type!], the second argument is optional - hence not needing an extra arg for the last call.

Comment: similar vodoo works in almost all languages :) 
 
made that for java

Comment: @masterX244 The difference being that most of those require some trickery with parens or other syntax to cause the reversal.  I figured this would be a good addition because without the single first line, the code is still valid as-is

Comment: @lzkata i didnt said exact identical; just similar; someone in PHP did something related with weird operator behavior

Answer (score 1):

## Coffeescript

This one is using coffeescript, by overriding the console.log function to skip the `undefined` second argument.

```
c = window.console
console =
  log: () ->
    c.log arguments[0]
    c.log arguments[1] if arguments[1]
console.log "Line1", 
console.log "Line2", 
console.log "Line3", 
console.log "Line4"
```

Answer (score 1):

**My version in batch - using "batch file reflection" ;)**

This one actually supports up to 9 statements to be executed backwards (but can easily be expanded to support more), and they could be almost any kind of commands - not just print statements!

The only rules are that the statements which you want to run reversed must appear in the file between the "rem BEGIN_REV" and "rem END_REV" comments, and that the file name you run it as must end in .BAT (not .CMD!).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ffrag=FILEFRAG%random%

call :run %0
goto :eof

rem BEGIN_REV
echo Line1
echo Line2
echo Line3
echo Line4
rem END_REV

:run

set me=%1
set me=%me:.bat=%.bat
set /a isOn=0
set /a incrCount=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%me%) do (
    set ln=
    set ln=%%i

    if !isOn!==0 (
        set d=
        set d=!ln:begin_rev=!

        if not !d!==!ln! (
            rem Starting block
            set /a isOn=1
        )
    ) else (
        rem Inside block

        set /a incrCount=!incrCount!+1
        echo !ln! > %ffrag%_!incrCount!.b

        set d=
        set d=!ln:END_REV=!

        if not !d!==!ln! (
            rem End of block reached
            goto :endloop
        )
    )
)

:endloop

del %ffrag%_%incrCount%.b

for /f %%i in ('dir /s/b/O:-N %ffrag%*') do (
    type %%i >> %ffrag%_FINAL.bat
)

del %ffrag%*.b
call %ffrag%_FINAL.bat
del %ffrag%_FINAL.bat
```

Output:

```
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python3

```
print('line1') if not (
print('line2') if not (
print('line3') if not 
print('line4') else 
0) else 0) else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python3

```
def print(x,p=
print):p(x[:-1]+str(5-int(x[-1])))
print("line1")
print("line2")
print("line3")
print("line4")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala

```
object PrintRev extends App{
    val rev : (=>Unit,=>Unit,=>Unit,=>Unit) => Unit = (v1,v2,v3,v4) => {v4;v3;v2;v1}
    rev(println("Line1"),
      println("Line2"),
      println("Line3"),
      println("Line4"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Plain ol' Simple JavaScript

No loops, no arrays, no reversals, no string manipulation, no new function definitions, just plain ol' JS `console.log()`:

```js
console.log("Line1",
console.log("Line2",
console.log("Line3",
console.log("Line4"
)||'')||'')||'')
```

(Partially inspired by [bwoebi's (oft-adapted) PHP entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20693/8856).)

A slightly more interesting/specific variant:

```js
console.log("Line1".valueOf(
console.log("Line2".valueOf(
console.log("Line3".valueOf(
console.log("Line4"
)))))))
```

The trick here is not just precedence, but also the fact that `valueOf` is a function that takes no arguments, and thus acts as an identity function. Unlike other precedence-based solutions, there's no need to rely on type coercion for empty-string concatenation or boolean logic. Just plain damn, built-in JS. :]

Answer (score 1):

### Perl

```
eval ($_) for (   reverse split("\n", <<EOF
print "Line1"; 
print "Line2"; 
print "Line3"; 
print "Line4";
EOF
) );
```

Very simple perl-Example with eval...

Answer (score 1):

### Python

there's my code :)

```
import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')

print 'Line 1'
print 'Line 2'
print 'Line 3'
print 'Line 4'

sys.stdout = old_stdout

a = open('file.txt','r').read().splitlines()
a.sort(reverse=True)

print '\n'.join(a)
```

Comment: plain old stdout remap :) but works :P +1

Answer (score 1):

#### Python 2.7 (may work down to 2.4)

Tested with CPython 2.7.5 and PyPy 2.0.2

```
def inv(fn):
    import types
    t=fn.__code__
    c=list(t.co_code)
    idxs=[i+1 for i,j in enumerate(c) if j=='d' and c[i+1]!='\0']
    for i in range(len(idxs)/2):
        c[idxs[i]], c[idxs[-i-1]] = c[idxs[-i-1]], c[idxs[i]]
    outcode=types.CodeType( t.co_argcount, t.co_nlocals, t.co_stacksize, t.co_flags, ''.join(c), t.co_consts, t.co_names, t.co_varnames, t.co_filename, t.co_name, t.co_firstlineno, t.co_lnotab)
    return types.FunctionType(outcode, globals(), fn.__name__[::-1])

@inv
def f():
    print 'Line1'
    print 'Line2'
    print 'Line3'
    print 'Line4'

f()
```

http://ideone.com/A2AJ2s

A somewhat more secure approach requires changing the `inv` function to something like this:

```
def inv(fn):
    import types
    import dis

    t=fn.__code__
    c=list(t.co_code)

    idxs=[]
    i=0
    n=len(c)
    lc=dis.opmap['LOAD_CONST']

    while i<n:
        opcode=ord(c[i])
        if opcode==lc and c[i+1]!='\0':
            idxs+=[i+1]
        i+=1
        if opcode>=dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT:
            i+=2

    for i in range(len(idxs)/2):
        c[idxs[i]], c[idxs[-i-1]] = c[idxs[-i-1]], c[idxs[i]]
    outcode=types.CodeType( t.co_argcount, t.co_nlocals, t.co_stacksize, t.co_flags, ''.join(c), t.co_consts, t.co_names, t.co_varnames, t.co_filename, t.co_name, t.co_firstlineno, t.co_lnotab)
    return types.FunctionType(outcode, globals(), fn.__name__[::-1])
```

http://ideone.com/8WgMxk

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell

```
import Prelude (print, return, (>>=))

main = do
   print "Line 1"
   print "Line 2"
   print "Line 3"
   print "Line 4"

a>>b=b>>= \_->a
```

Run with

> $ runhaskell -XRebindableSyntax reversed.hs

(Note that without the `RebindableSyntax` flag, it's still a valid Haskell program and will print in the normal order)

---

Standard Haskell98 alternative:

```
import Prelude hiding (print)

main = r$do
   print "Line 1"
   print "Line 2"
   print "Line 3"
   print "Line 4"

data R a=R{r::IO a}
instance Monad R where R a>>=b=R$r(b u)>>= \_->fmap u a;return=R .return
print=R .putStrLn
u::u;u=u
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#

Kind of lame, just my two cents:

```
var printMeReverse = new List<Action> {
    new Action(() => Console.WriteLine ("Line1")),
    new Action(() => Console.WriteLine ("Line2")),
    new Action(() => Console.WriteLine ("Line3")),
    new Action(() => Console.WriteLine ("Line4"))
};
printMeReverse.Reverse();
printMeReverse.ForEach(a => a.Invoke());
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Powershell

```
"line1`n" `
-replace "^","line2`n" `
-replace "^","line3`n" `
-replace "^","line4`n"
```

I'm not sure if line continuation chars are cheating or not, but they've not been explicity banned ;-)

Alternatively without line continuation:

```
("line1",
"line2",
"line3",
"line4")[3..0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java

This is another, but different `System.out` abuse:

```java
public class PrintBackwards {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Line1");
        System.out.println("Line2");
        System.out.println("Line3");
        System.out.println("Line4");
    }

    public static class System {

        public static class out {

            public static void println(String val) {
                Print.println(val);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Print {

    private static java.util.Stack<String> s = new java.util.Stack<>();

    public static void println(String val) {
        s.push(val);
        if (s.size() >= 4) {
            while (!s.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(s.pop());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The best thing about it: the main method is unchanged.

Comment: thats lol; abusing inner classes to nullify System from tje JDK in mainclass:P

Comment: @masterX244 I considered doing `java.lang.System.out.println` instead of a secondary class, but I think that this way, it is more unclear.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript**

Monkeypatching for the win!

```
var oldAlert = alert;
var buf = [];
alert = function(v)
{
    if(v != undefined)
        buf.push(v);
    else
    {
        while(buf.length > 0)
            oldAlert(buf.pop());
    }
}
alert("line 1");
alert("line 2");
alert("line 3");
alert("line 4");
alert();
```

Answer (score 1):

**JS/Node**

```
(function() {
  while (arguments.length > 0) {
    eval([].pop.call(arguments));
  }
}).apply(this, [
'console.log("Line1")',
'console.log("Line2")',
'console.log("Line3")',
'console.log("Line4")'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3

```
[a(b) for a,b in (
    (print, "Line1"),
    (print, "Line2"),
    (print, "Line3"),
    (print, "Line4"))[::-1]]
```

Which is sadly not compliant to the contest rules, due to four unfortunate commas, but I so love abusing comprehensions with side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6

```
END say 'Line1';
END say 'Line2';
END say 'Line3';
END say 'Line4';
```

There's a lot more [phasers](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S04.html#Phasers) where `END` came from :)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3

Redefining print

```
import sys

old_print = print

strings = []

def print(thing):
    strings.append(thing)

    if thing == "Line 4":
        for thing in reversed(strings):
            old_print(thing)

print("Line 1")
print("Line 2")
print("Line 3")
print("Line 4")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (abusing eval)

```
eval(File.readlines(__FILE__).reverse.join "\n")
exit
puts "Line 1"
puts "Line 2"
puts "Line 3"
puts "Line 4"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala

```
implicit class Abuse(string: String) {
    def print(o: String) = o + string
    def print = println(string)
}

"Line1" print
"Line2" print
"Line3" print
"Line4" print
```

Note the abusive use of semicolon insertion, and postfix operators, and the (almost legitimate) use of implicits.

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```
import sys

class revout():
    def __init__(self):
        self.out = sys.stdout
        self.buffer = ""
    def write(self,a):
        self.buffer += a
    def unclog(self):
        self.out.write("\n".join(self.buffer.split("\n")[::-1]))

sys.stdout = revout()

print "Line 1"
print "Line 2"
print "Line 3"
print "Line 4",

sys.stdout.unclog()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala

```
object Backwards {
  def print(msg: String): String = msg

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    (
    print("Line 1") ::
    print("Line 2") ::
    print("Line 3") ::
    print("Line 4") ::
    List()).reverse.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8

Abusing lambdas

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Backwards {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reverse(
                print -> "Line 1",
                print -> "Line 2",
                print -> "Line 3",
                print -> "Line 4"
            );
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static void reverse(Function<Integer, String>... funcs) {
        for (int i = funcs.length; i --> 0; ) {
            System.out.println(funcs[i].apply(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Note the artful use of the "goes to" operator.

Answer (score 1):

The very lazy C# method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace P
{
    static class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Stack<Action> s = new Stack<Action>();
            s.Push(() => Console.WriteLine("Line1"));
            s.Push(() => Console.WriteLine("Line2"));
            s.Push(() => Console.WriteLine("Line3"));
            s.Push(() => Console.WriteLine("Line4"));
            foreach (var a in s) a();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And a version with using aliases (not sure if it's shorter or not, cba to count)

```
using C = System.Console;
using SA = System.Collections.Generic.Stack<System.Action>;

namespace P
{
    static class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            SA s = new SA();
            s.Push(() => C.WriteLine("Line1"));
            s.Push(() => C.WriteLine("Line2"));
            s.Push(() => C.WriteLine("Line3"));
            s.Push(() => C.WriteLine("Line4"));
            foreach (var a in s) a();
            C.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't it nice when code writes itself?

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript**

```
eval(
        "console.log('line1');"+
        "console.log('line2');"+
        "console.log('line3');"+
        "console.log('line4')"
        .split(";").reverse().join(";"));
```

Answer (score 1):

## F#

```
""
    |> sprintf "Line1 %s"
    |> sprintf "Line2 %s"
    |> sprintf "Line3 %s"
    |> sprintf "Line4 %s"
    |> printfn "%s"
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript

```javascript
eval(
'console.log("Line1"); \
console.log("Line2"); \
console.log("Line3"); \
console.log("Line4"); '
.split(";").reverse().join(";"))
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>

std::vector <char *> *lines = new std::vector <char *>();

void print(char *text)
{
    lines->push_back(text);
}

class Dummy 
{
public:
    ~Dummy()
    {
        for(int i = lines->size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            std::cout << lines->at(i) << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

void PrintLines()
{
    Dummy d;
    print("Line 1");
    print("Line 2");
    print("Line 3");
    print("Line 4");
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PrintLines();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

A bad technique, still it works.

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk

```
#("
/*code*/ print "Line1" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line2" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line3" /*code*/
/*code*/ print "Line4" /*code*/
") reverse do: [:s| Transcript cr; show: s].
```

It's mostly the same as the other smalltalk answer, but inspired in the common lisp literal one.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 and 3

Reverses the order of statements using abstract syntax tree manipulation.

```
a = __import__('ast').parse(open(__file__).read())
a.body = list(reversed(a.body[4:]))
exec(compile(a, '', 'exec'))
exit()
print("Line 1")
print("Line 2")
print("Line 3")
print("Line 4")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](http://factorcode.org/)

```
[ print "line1"
  print "line2"
  print "line3"
  print "line4" ]
 reverse call
```

Similar to the Common Lisp, Rebol, and Bash+tac answers, actually reverses the code before executing it.

Code-is-data + RPN = Most direct solution... even too trivial to be interesting maybe?

Answer (score 1):

**Java**

Idea borrowed from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28818/30538). Reverses the values used by the Integer class.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Print4
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class cache = Integer.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0];
        Field c = cache.getDeclaredField("cache");
        c.setAccessible(true);
        Integer[] array = (Integer[]) c.get(cache);
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array).subList(129, 133));

        System.out.printf("Line %d \n", 1);
        System.out.printf("Line %d \n", 2);
        System.out.printf("Line %d \n", 3);
        System.out.printf("Line %d \n", 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++

I can't believe there was not still a `std::stack` based solution!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<function<void()>> instructions;
    
    instructions.push([](){cout<<"Line 1"<<endl;});
    instructions.push([](){cout<<"Line 2"<<endl;});
    instructions.push([](){cout<<"Line 3"<<endl;});
    instructions.push([](){cout<<"Line 4"<<endl;});
    
    while(!instructions.empty())
    {
        instructions.top()();
        instructions.pop();
    }
}
```

---

[demo](http://rextester.com/USP55518)

Answer (score 1):

## C++

Abusing Right-to-Left interpretation order of parameters

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void dummy_function(ostream &a, ostream &b, ostream &c, ostream &)
{
}   

int main()
{
    dummy_function(
        cout<<"Line 1"<<endl,
        cout<<"Line 2"<<endl,
        cout<<"Line 3"<<endl,
        cout<<"Line 4"<<endl
   );
}
```

---

[demo](http://rextester.com/PZHSUM52600)

Comment: `ostream &`huh?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: what's the problem?

Comment: Does `&` go on its own? Otherwise you have a syntax error.

Comment: It compiled, as you can see in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

## R

Despite the fact that this contest ended some time ago, I would like to leave an answer in my favourite language for the sake of completeness. Also, this has been discussed on [Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15012/is-it-acceptable-to-answer-an-old-question) that reanimating old question is not bad and sometimes encouraged.

```
sink("a.txt")
cat("Line1\n")
cat("Line2\n")
cat("Line3\n")
cat("Line4\n")
sink()
cat(rev(readLines("a.txt")), sep="\n")
```

This programme writes four lines to an external file, then imports it as a vector of strings and prints them out in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC

```
WHILE 1
 WHILE B
  WHILE C
   WHILE D
    PRINT "Line1"
    END
   WEND
   PRINT "Line2"
   D=1
  WEND
  PRINT "Line3"
  C=1
 WEND
 PRINT "Line4"
 B=1
WEND
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 50 bytes

```perl
say"Line 1"x
say"line 2"x
say"Line 3"x
say"Line 4"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJJzMvVcFQqYILxMkBcYygHLCMMTLHROn//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby

This syntax is somewhat confusing.

```
eval <<print.split($/)*'unless '
print "Line1"
print "Line2"
print "Line3"
print "Line4"
print
```

Answer (score 0):

## GolfScript

```
"Line1"
"Line2"
"Line3"
"Line4"
{.puts}do
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP

```
<?php

class D          {function D(){echo 'Line1';            }}
class C extends D{function C(){echo 'Line2';parent::D();}}
class B extends C{function B(){echo 'Line3';parent::C();}}
class A extends B{function A(){echo 'Line4';parent::B();}}
new A();
```

maximum of 60 bytes :)

Comment: If you do this, why not just have functions calling each other?

Comment: Yes, I can (use OOP).^^

Answer (score 0):

## Julia

```
macro rev(a)
    eval(a).args = flipud(eval(a).args);a
end

p=quote
    println("Line1")
    println("Line2")
    println("Line3")
    println("Line4")
  end

rp = @rev(p)
eval(rp)
```

It's overkill but I wanted to do something with macros and expressions.  `p` is an expression object (an object representing parsed code), `@rev` operates on the expression to create a new expression `rp` with the lines reversed, then I `eval` the new expression. Should work to reverse execution for an arbitrary amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

## C

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myPrint(char *arg) {
  static int count = 0
  static char **lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 4);
  char[count] = arg;
  ++count;
  if (count >= 4) {
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; --i) {
      puts(lines[i]);
    }
  }
}

#define print myPrint

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  print("Line 1");
  print("Line 2");
  print("Line 3");
  print("Line 4");
  return -1;
}

#undef print
```

I didn't test it, so there may be syntax errors, segfaults or undefined behaviour, but I think the general idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

## C#

A delegate that returns itself:

```c#
using System;

delegate A A(Action a);

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Magic()
            (() => Console.WriteLine("Line1"))
            (() => Console.WriteLine("Line2"))
            (() => Console.WriteLine("Line3"))
            (() => Console.WriteLine("Line4"))
            (null);
    }

    static A Magic()
    {
        Action prev = () => { };
        A result = null;
        result = a =>
        {
            if (a == null)
                prev();
            else
            {
                var prevPrev = prev;
                prev = () =>
                {
                    a();
                    prevPrev();
                };
            }
            return result;
        };

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript - Without relying on the event loop***

```
var p = function (v, c) { if (c) { c(); } console.log(v); }
p('Line 1', function() { p ('Line 2', function () { p ('Line 3', function () { p('Line 4'); })})});
```

Result:

```
Line 4
Line 3
Line 2
Line 1
```

Comment: This doesn't contain Line1, Line2, etc. at all, which, according to spec, it should.

Comment: You are correct... That was oversight on my part but I have corrected it... It now includes Line 1, Line 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch

I don't know if this technically allowed..

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=~" %%a in (
    "echo Line1
    ~echo Line2
    ~echo Line3
    ~echo Line4"
) do %%d & %%c & %%b & %%a
```

Given the requirement in the question, of no spaces when using line feed -

> Line4\nLine3\nLine2\nLine1

The last line should be -

```
) do %%d&%%c&%%b&%%a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash

```
$ x=
$ print () {
>     x=$1$x
> }
$ print 1
$ print 2
$ print 3
$ print 4
$ echo $x
```

Define `print` as tacking the passed argument on to the beginning of a variable; clear it before and print it after.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby

```
["print 'Line1'",
"print 'Line2'",
"print 'Line3'",
"print 'Line4'"].reverse.each {|l| eval "#{l}"}

#=> Line4Line3Line2Line1
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP

```
    $a = array(
        function(){print "Line 1\n";},
        function(){print "Line 2\n";},
        function(){print "Line 3\n";},
        function(){print "Line 4\n";},
    );
    foreach (array_reverse($a) as $l) { $l(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 1.8

See [Javascript 1.8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8) and [browser support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history).

```
console.log([
    'print "Line1"',
    'print "Line2"',
    'print "Line3"',
    'print "Line4"'
    ].reduceRight(
        function(p,s) p + s.match(/"(.*)"/)[1],
        ""
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## q

Very easy in a language with "left-of-right" evaluation.

```
(show "Line1"),
(show "Line2"),
(show "Line3"),
show "Line4"
```

"Line4"

"Line3"

"Line2"

"Line1"

edit: formatted code to fit one print per line rule, though q ignores white space so I'm not sure this counts

Comment: Please use Markdown to format the [code block](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) appropriately.

Comment: Are you sure your code not violates the “Every line can contain only one `print`” rule?

Comment: q ignores white space, so I may be in violation

Answer (score 0):

## main-while-loop and if switches (Python)

```
next = 4
while next:
    if next == 1: print "Line1"
    if next == 2: print "Line2"
    if next == 3: print "Line3"
    if next == 4: print "Line4"
    next -= 1
```

Comment: tip: read the rules; 3rd bullet says; avoid simple loops with ifs or similar

Answer (score 0):

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#define print(s) std::cout << s << "\n"; return g; }
#define f []{ auto g = 

int main() {
    f f f f []{};
    print ("Line 1");
    print ("Line 2");
    print ("Line 3");
    print ("Line 4")
    ()()()()();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple T-SQL Solution**

The code here is not "organic" (not part of the raw code body), though, unlike my other batch solution.

```
set nocount on

declare @t table (stmt nvarchar(500))
declare @stmt nvarchar(500)

insert into @t values 
('print ''Line1'''),
('print ''Line2'''),
('print ''Line3'''),
('print ''Line4''')

select top 1 @stmt = stmt from @t order by stmt desc

while @@rowcount > 0 begin
    exec(@stmt)
    delete from @t where stmt = @stmt
    select top 1 @stmt = stmt from @t order by stmt desc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**PowerShell**

```
(   {Write-Host 'Line 1'},
    {Write-Host 'Line 2'},
    {Write-Host 'Line 3'},
    {Write-Host 'Line 4'}
)[3..0]|ForEach-Object {Invoke-Command $_}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7

```
for l in """
print "Line1"
print "Line2"
print "Line3"
print "Line4"
""".splitlines()[::-1]:
    exec(l)
```

you can see the result here: http://ideone.com/QypGiB

`a[::-1]` represents the reversed list a.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3

```
import sys

plist = []
cout = 0

def print(s):
    global cout
    plist.append(s+"\n")
    cout += 1
    if cout == 4:
        for i in reversed(plist):
            sys.stdout.write(i)

print("Line 1")
print("Line 2")
print("Line 3")
print("Line 4")
```

Output (escaped):

```
"Line4\nLine3\nLine2\nLine1\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `tac $0 | head -n 4` && exit
echo 'Line1' ;
echo 'Line2' ;
echo 'Line3' ;
echo 'Line4' ;
```

Output:

```
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

Answer (score 0):

**More fun with BASH arrays**

```
#!/bin/bash
a=("echo Line1"  
   "echo Line2"
   "echo Line3"
   "echo Line4")
for (( i=${#a[@]}-1; i>=0; i-- )) ; do
  eval ${a[i]}
done
```

Output:

```
Line4
Line3
Line2
Line1
```

Answer (score 0):

**One more from the Bash command-line:**

```
echo "Line1" "Line2" "Line3" "Line4" | { read a b c d; echo $d $c $b $a; }
```

Output:

```
Line4 Line3 Line2 Line1
```

Here is a version expanded to multiple lines to match the exact syntax of the spec:

```
echo "Line1" < \
echo "Line2" < \
echo "Line3" < \
echo "Line4" | { read a b c d; echo $d; echo $c; echo $b; echo $a; }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk (79/66/143 chars)

#### version 1 (79):

```
{
    [ 'line1' print ].
    [ 'line2' print ].
    [ 'line3' print ].
    [ 'line4' print ]
} reverse map:#value
```

little explanation:
[..] is a block (aka lambda closure);
{..} is an array constructor;
reverse and map are obvious;
 #value evaluates a block closure.

#### output:

line4line3line2line1

#### version 2 (66):

Here is a version using reflection; it fetches the string constants of the block and prints them:

Given any block containing string-prints:

```
b := [
    'line1' print.
    'line2' print.
    'line3' print.
    'line4' print
].
```

where 'normal' evaluation with:

```
b value.
```

gives: line1line2line3line4l

The following extracts the string literals and prints them reverse:

```
(b method literals select:[:l|l class==String]) reverse map:#print
```

gives: line4line3line2line1

the code is a little unsafe (it requires that the block's containing method does not contain other string literals; but we are playing golf - not trusted software development ;-)

#### version 3 (143)

defines a 'function' which redirects stdout to some internal stream, evaluates a block closure and finally prints the collected output in reverse:

```
w := [:b | |sav red|
  [
      sav := Stdout.
      Stdout := red := '' writeStream.
      b value.
  ] ensure:[
      Stdout := sav.
      red contents asCollectionOfLines reverse map:#printNL
  ]
].
```

then we evaluate any code within that wrapper:

```
w value:[
 'line1' printNL.
 'line2' printNL.
 'line3' printNL.
 'line4' printNL
]
```

its not thread save, though.

(all character counts are w.o omittable whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

## Coffeescript

revision 2: not as coffeescriptic but smaller

```
do(c=console)->c.log "Line1" if!c
.log "Line2" if!c
.log "Line3" if!c
.log "Line4"
```

revision 1:

```
do(c=console)->c.log "Line1" unless c
.log "Line2" unless c
.log "Line3" unless c
.log "Line4"
```

*Single line variant*:

```
do(c=console)->c.log "Line1" unless c.log "Line2" unless c.log "Line3" unless c.log "Line4"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### F#

(Ab)using custom keywords in a computation expression.

```
type Reverse = Reverse with
    [<CustomOperation "print">]
    member this.Print(l, x) = x :: l
    member this.Yield(_) = []
    member this.Run(l) = List.iter (printfn "%s") l

Reverse {
    print "Line1"
    print "Line2"
    print "Line3"
    print "Line4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Shell again

```
cat <<XXX | sort -r | sh -
echo Line 1
echo Line 2
echo Line 3
echo Line 4
XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2

Using the much maligned inline if-else

```
from sys import stdout
stdout.write('Line 1\n') if (stdout.write('Line 2\n') if (stdout.write('Line 3\n') if stdout.write('Line 4\n') or 1 else 0) or 1 else 0) or 1 else 0
```

Comment: The rule says, “Every line can contain only one `print`”.

Answer (score 0):

### Java

This is an alternative to the `System.out` abuse in the other submission, by abusing the `PrintStream` instead (the `out`).

```
class MyPrintStream extends PrintStream {
    String t = "";

    public MyPrintStream() {
        super(System.out);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyPrintStream.super.println(t);
            }
        });
    }

    public void println(String s) {
        t = s + "\n" + t;
    }
}

public class Temp {
    static {
        System.setOut(new MyPrintStream());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Line 1");
        System.out.println("Line 2");
        System.out.println("Line 3");
        System.out.println("Line 4");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output_list = []
class newstdout():
    def write(self, s):
        output_list.append(s)

stdout, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, newstdout()

print("Line 1")
print("Line 2")
print("Line 3")

sys.stdout = stdout
_ = [print(s, end='') for s in output_list[::-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Objective-C

```
#define NSLog(a) NSLog( [self changeNumber:(NSString*)a])
...
    NSLog(@"Line1");
    NSLog(@"Line2");
    NSLog(@"Line3");
    NSLog(@"Line4");
...
- (NSString *)changeNumber:(NSString *)string
{
    int number = [string substringFromIndex:string.length-1].intValue;
    int newnumber = -number + 5;
    NSString *newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number] withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newnumber]];
    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure

Using clojure macro.

```
(defmacro do-reverse [& v]
 `(do 
    ~@(reverse v)))

(do-reverse
 (println "Line 1")
 (println "Line 2")
 (println "Line 3")
 (println "Line 4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2**

```
import inspect

def main():
    print "Line 1"
    print "Line 2"
    print "Line 3"
    print "Line 4"

for line in inspect.getsourcelines(main)[0][:0:-1]:
    exec(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

### SHELL

```
_rp() { 
    eval "printf '%s\\n' \
        \"\${$(seq -s'}" "${' $# -1 1)}\""
}
```

Hand that a list of shell arguments and it will print them back at you in reverse. It works by `eval`uating the output of GNU's `seq`uence into a shell quoted list of positional parameters.

#### DEMO

```
set -vx
_rp one two three

###OUTPUT

+ _rp one two three
seq -s'}" "${' $# -1 1
++ seq '-s}" "${' 3 -1 1
+ eval 'printf '\''%s\n'\'' "${3}" "${2}" "${1}"'
printf '%s\n' "${3}" "${2}" "${1}"
++ printf '%s\n' three two one
three
two
one
```

From that point on you can just define `IFS` as necessary when invoking it in order to split among the arguments as you please.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

Sort of a translation of Gareth's Perl answer

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("Line1")},200);
setTimeout(function(){alert("Line2")},140);
setTimeout(function(){alert("Line3")},80);
setTimeout(function(){alert("Line4")},20);
```

Answer (score 0):

## [DC](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Dc)

File `rev3.dc`:

```
[[line 1]PAP]
[[line 2]PAP]
[[line 3]PAP]
[[line 4]PAP]
xxxx
```

This pushes the print actions on the stack and executes them by `x` (== pop and execute).

Run:

```
$ dc -f rev3.dc 
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#

Simply using a Stack of type Action to store lambdas that execute Console.WriteLine. As the nature of a stack dictates the last "pushed" Action will be "popped" first.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new Stack<Action>();
        s.Push(() => { Console.WriteLine("Line1"); });
        s.Push(() => { Console.WriteLine("Line2"); });
        s.Push(() => { Console.WriteLine("Line3"); });
        s.Push(() => { Console.WriteLine("Line4"); });
        while (s.Count > 0)
        {
            s.Pop().Invoke();
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl/Tk

```
pack [label .l1 -text "Line 1"] -side bottom
pack [label .l2 -text "Line 2"] -side bottom
pack [label .l3 -text "Line 3"] -side bottom
pack [label .l4 -text "Line 4"] -side bottom
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## C++

Based on [my own C++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123242/29325), but next level: no functors and no lambdas!
Just function pointers!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

void f1() {cout<<"Line 1"<<endl;}
void f2() {cout<<"Line 2"<<endl;}
void f3() {cout<<"Line 3"<<endl;}
void f4() {cout<<"Line 4"<<endl;}

int main()
{
    stack<void(*)()> instructions;
     
    instructions.push(f1);
    instructions.push(f2);
    instructions.push(f3);
    instructions.push(f4);
   
    while(!instructions.empty())
    {
        instructions.top()();
        instructions.pop();
    }
}
```

---

[demo](http://rextester.com/BTJLM41651)