# Translate ASCII text to braille

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that translates ASCII text to [braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille) output. Requirements:

- Input may come from stdin, command line, or some other external input source.
- Output should be recognisable as braille, the form of output is up to you. An example would be `o` for a raised dot and `.` for a non-raised dot. Textual pattern representation such as `1-3-4` is not acceptable. Long line wrapping is not required.
- Only the 26 alphabet characters and space are required for a minimal solution. All input characters not supported by your solution should be ignored.

Scoring is by number of characters in the source code. Penalties and bonuses are:

- +50 penalty for using [Unicode braille characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_Patterns) as output.
- -50 bonus for supporting capitals, numbers, and punctuation.
- <strike>-200 bonus for supporting ligatures and one-letter contractions from [English (Grade-2) Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Braille).</strike> (Will make this a separate challenge since it's quite a different problem.)

Sample invocation and output (minimal solution):

```
$ braille Hello world
o .  o .  o .  o .  o .  . .  . o  o .  o .  o .  o o
o o  . o  o .  o .  . o  . .  o o  . o  o o  o .  . o
. .  . .  o .  o .  o .  . .  . o  o .  o .  o .  . .
```

Comment: define "valiant attempt". Also, is  line-wrapping required?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Thanks, updated question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but a single example doesn't cut it in a code golf specification. Please give us the objective minimal requirements to qualify for the bonus.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Fair point, I've removed the "valiant attempt" weasel words. There is considerable variation in real world use of these contractions, and fully spelling out contractable words using only letters is valid but considered clumsy by braille readers.

Comment: What punctuation do we need to support? Some symbols don't have a standard braille equivalent.

Comment: @qwr the basic punctuation listed in the braille Wikipedia article.

Comment: @GregHewgill Can you make the bonus for including capitals, numbers, and punctuation larger? Currently that's 26+10+12 = 48 extra characters, not much of a bonus (unless you compress the braille data)

Comment: @qwr: I'm not going to change the bonus at this point. Note that capitals aren't separate letter codes, but a prefix code that means "the next letter is capital".

Comment: You could count bytes instead of characters and remove the penalty, the cost is about the same (@DigitalTrauma's first solution is 85 bytes). **Edit:** I just realized that would penalize languages like APL. It's up to you.

Comment: can the output be vertical?

Comment: Man... the penalty for unicode chars isn't big enough to make this interesting. I wanted to see how people were going to encode the braille set.

Comment: Which English grade-2 Braille? American, British or Unified?

Comment: @aditsu: I'm probably going to make the Grade-2 challenge a separate problem, and specify the requirements carefully.

Comment: @GregHewgill from what I've seen around here (to my dismay), that would likely get a bunch of downvotes and be closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Python, 162

```
l=map((" a c,bif/e d:hjg'k m;lsp o n!rtq%12s. w -u x v   z y"%'').find,raw_input().lower())
for i in 1,4,16:print'  '.join('.o.o    ..oo'[(n&i*3)/i::4]for n in l)
```

Currently supports lowercase letters and some punctuation, but it's still a work in progress.

Example:

```
$ python braille.py
Hello, world!
o .  o .  o .  o .  o .  . .  . .  . o  o .  o .  o .  o o  . .
o o  . o  o .  o .  . o  o .  . .  o o  . o  o o  o .  . o  o o
. .  . .  o .  o .  o .  . .  . .  . o  o .  o .  o .  . .  o .
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python - <strike>90</strike> 75 + 50 = 125

Use lower case letters.

```
for l in input():
 a=ord(l)-96
 if a<0:a=0
 print("⠀⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠺⠭⠽⠵"[a],end="")
```

One-liner (thanks to ɐɔıʇǝɥʇuʎs)

```
for l in input():print("⠀⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠺⠭⠽⠵"[max(0,ord(l)-96)],end="")
```

Comment: Why not make it a one-liner? `for l in input():print("⠀⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠺⠭⠽⠵"[max(0,ord(l)-96)],end="")` 75 characters.

Comment: @ɐɔıʇǝɥʇuʎs wow, I forgot about the `max` trick. Thank you

Comment: You can save a char by just putting blanks for all non-letter characters: `for l in input():print((" "*97+"⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠺⠭⠽⠵")[ord(l)],end="")`

Answer (score 5):

## BBC Basic 103 ASCII characters or 92 tokens

```
A$="HXIKJY[ZQShxikjy{zqsl|Wmon"FORK=1TO26A=ASC(MID$(A$,K))VDU23,K+96,A AND9;0,A/2AND9;0,A/4AND9;:NEXT
```

Possibly not quite what the OP intended, this redefines the font for the lowercase characters. `VDU 23,n,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h` assigns an 8x8 bitmap to character n, consisting of eight bytes. Following a parameter with a semicolon instead of a comma causes it to be treated as a two-byte little-endian number.

The braille patterns for letters `a` through `z` are stored in A$, according to the following bit pattern. This is extracted by masks with 9=binary`1001` and rightshifts (division by 2 and 4 is used as standard BBC basic has no shift operator.)

```
 8 1
16 2
32 4
```

**Ungolfed code**

```
A$="HXIKJY[ZQShxikjy{zqsl|Wmon"
FORK=1TO26
  A=ASC(MID$(A$,K))
  VDU23,K+96,A AND9;0,A/2AND9;0,A/4AND9;
NEXT
```

**Usage example**

This is done in screen mode 6 for clarity (type MODE6 as soon as you open the command line emulator.)

Actually, after running the code, any lowercase letters (including keyboard input) appear in Braille.

[image]

Emulator at  http://bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/bbcwin.html.

See also this similar answer of mine: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28869/15599

Answer (score 3):

## C, 269

```c
#define C char
#define O*p++=(*t&1)*65+46;*t>>=1;
main(int c,C**v){C b[99]={1,5,3,11,9,7,15,13,6,14},o[99],*q=o,*p=v[1],*t;while(c=*p++)*q++=c=='w'?46:c>='a'&&c<='z'?c-='a'+(c>'w'),b[c%10]|(c>9)*16|(c>19)*32:0;for(c=3;c;c--){p=b;for(t=o;t<q;t++){O;O*p++=32;}puts(b);}}
```

This implementation requires that its argument, if it contains spaces, must be quoted:

```
# braille "hello world"
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + coreutils

#### Minimal solution - lowercase only, 83 (33 unicode chars + 50 penalty):

```
tr a-z ⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠭⠽⠵⠺
```

#### Capitals, numbers and punctuation, 120 (120 unicode chars + 50 penalty - 50 bonus):

```
a=⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠭⠽⠵⠺
sed 's/\([0-9]\)/⠼&/g;s/\([A-Z]\)/⠠&/g'|tr ",;':\-⎖.!“?”()/a-zA-Z1-90" ⠂⠆⠄⠒⠤⠨⠲⠖⠦⠦⠴⠶⠶⠌$a$a$a
```

Example output:

```
$ echo {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} ".,;:" | ./braille.sh 
⠠⠁ ⠠⠃ ⠠⠉ ⠠⠙ ⠠⠑ ⠠⠋ ⠠⠛ ⠠⠓ ⠠⠊ ⠠⠚ ⠠⠅ ⠠⠇ ⠠⠍ ⠠⠝ ⠠⠕ ⠠⠏ ⠠⠟ ⠠⠗ ⠠⠎ ⠠⠞ ⠠⠥ ⠠⠧ ⠠⠭ ⠠⠽ ⠠⠵ ⠠⠺ ⠁ ⠃ ⠉ ⠙ ⠑ ⠋ ⠛ ⠓ ⠊ ⠚ ⠅ ⠇ ⠍ ⠝ ⠕ ⠏ ⠟ ⠗ ⠎ ⠞ ⠥ ⠧ ⠭ ⠽ ⠵ ⠺ ⠼⠚ ⠼⠁ ⠼⠃ ⠼⠉ ⠼⠙ ⠼⠑ ⠼⠋ ⠼⠛ ⠼⠓ ⠼⠊ ⠲⠂⠆⠒
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam - 51

```
q{i32%"@`hptdx|lX\bjrvfz~nZ^ck]swg"=i2b1>2/}%zSf*N*
```

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

Example input:

```
braille is strange
```

Example output:

```
10 10 10 01 10 10 10 00 01 01 00 01 01 10 10 11 11 10 
10 11 00 10 10 10 01 00 10 10 00 10 11 11 00 01 11 01 
00 10 00 00 10 10 00 00 00 10 00 10 10 10 00 10 00 00
```

It only supports lowercase letters and space. Other characters are mapped to supported characters (in particular uppercase letters to lowercase).

**Explanation:**

Braille characters are encoded using 1 for a raised dot and 0 for a non-raised dot, left to right and top to bottom. This gives 6 base-2 digits; a 1 is prepended to avoid stripping leading zeros, then the number is converted to base 10 then to the corresponding ASCII character.
Example: t -> ⠞ -> 01/11/10 -> 1011110 -> 94 -> ^

The program converts back each character to the triplet of pairs of bits (such as `[[0 1][1 1][1 0]]`) obtaining a matrix of bit pairs. The matrix is then transposed and separators are added (spaces within rows, newlines between rows).

`q` reads the input into a string = array of characters
`{…}%` applies the block to each character
`i32%` gets the ASCII code mod 32 (space->0, a->1, b->2, z->26)
`` "@`hptdx|lX\bjrvfz~nZ^ck]swg" `` is a string containing the braille characters encoded as explained before
`=` gets the corresponding encoded braille character from the string
`i2b` gets the ASCII code then converts to base 2 (obtaining an array of 7 digits)
`1>` removes the leading 1 digit
`2/` splits the array into (3) pairs
`z` transposes the matrix
`Sf*` joins each row with spaces
`N*` joins the rows with newlines

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 81 + 50 - 50 = 81 bytes

```apl
(i,'⠚⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠲⠂⠒⠆⠦⠖ ',⍨i←'⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠺⠭⠽⠵')[(⎕A,⎕C⎕A,⎕D,'.,:;?! ')⍳⍞]
```

Try it online uses Dyalog 17, so `⎕C` is not supported in it. The alternative, `819⌶` (suggested by [dzaima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59183/dzaima)), has been used for demonstration purposes.

Braille symbols taken from [dcode.](https://www.dcode.fr/braille-alphabet)

### Explanation

```apl
                                                  ⍳⍞ Find index of each character of the input in the string..
                            (⎕A,⎕C⎕A,⎕D,'.,:;?! ')   A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and punctuation.
                           [                      ]  Pick characters from those indices..
(i,'⠚⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊....⠧⠺⠭⠽⠵')                          In the braille representation of the Alphanumeric and punctuation characters.
(last line is shortened to take up less space.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY49TgJRAIR7TvGoHiQPI/gDaGFMLLyBhaEg2cVs8sIaY6GlGkDFRdGgUSNOg9DYaLQw8TLfRdbVAzjFzNfMZJq7vhQcNn28UwoP9sN2EAYppz3TSguRs@gBHaETdIbu0RD10SO6QefoDR2ja9RFL@jWWEcyi@he2X972WoH9VCCntAIXaJndIcGaIwmaIq@0Cv6Rh@2uF1gMFp3tXKdi88/zGzD2Tm3srqWN7ZI8k4ybvy@T1u5zShTLsvQ@9hsxXs@yJtyZWFxablaq8//AA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - 286

```
w=prompt().split('');for(i=0;i<w.length;i++){z=w[i];o="o",p=".";b=[1,5,3,11,9,7,15,13,6,14];e=[c="",1,3];g=z.charCodeAt(0)-97;if(g>22)g--;f=e[g/10|0];d=b[g%10];if(g==22){d=14;f=2;}c+=d&1?o:p;c+=d&2?o:p;c+="\n";c+=d&4?o:p;c+=d&8?o:p;c+="\n";c+=f&1?o:p;c+=f&2?"o\n":".\n";console.log(c);}
```

First attempt. No bonuses.

Comment: You can reduce it to 279 with `w=prompt().split("");for(i=0;i<w.length;i++)z=w[i],o="o",p=".",b=[1,5,3,11,9,7,15,13,6,14],e=[c="",1,3],g=z.charCodeAt(0)-97,22<g&&g--,f=e[g/10|0],d=b[g%10],22==g&&(d=14,f=2),c+=d&1?o:p,c+=d&2?o:p,c+="\n",c+=d&4?o:p,c+=d&8?o:p,c+="\n",c+=f&1?o:p,c+=f&2?"o\n":".\n",console.log(c)`

Comment: Will have to remember that approach, nice long single statement for loop :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 331

```php
<?php $d=split("/",gzinflate(base64_decode("NYzBDQBACIM26o3G/r+LRf2QYAOZe4SCLKgU7A9lEWVOzrQVrAiwghWhLKLMyZlawTTGMIYxPg==")));$d[-65]="......";$i=str_split(preg_replace("/[^a-z ]/","",trim(fgets(STDIN))));$o=["","",""];$S="substr";foreach($i as $c){$v=ord($c)-97;for($x=0;$x<3;$x++)$o[$x].=$S($d[$v],$x*2,2)." ";}echo join($o,"\n");
```

No bonuses for now.

Comment: I think it's okay to use a short opening tag in [tag:code-golf], so you can use `<?` instead of `<?php[SPACE]` to save 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>249</s> 244

```
#define B?111:46
#define P(a,b)printf("%c%c ",a B,b B):
a,i;main(int c,char**v){for(char*p;p=v[1],a<3;puts(""),++a)while(i=*p++)i==32?P(0,0)i/97&122/i?c=(i+=(i==119)*17-97-(i>119))%10,a?a^1?P(i/10%3,i/20)P(c>4|c==1,c/3&&c%3-2)P(c<8,5*c/8%2)0;}
```

Input is a command-line argument, which must be escaped or quoted if the string contains spaces.  Supported characters are lowercase letters and space.  Unsupported characters are silently dropped.

**Edit:** Shaved 5 bytes by simplifying a condition

Answer (score 0):

### perl, 195+2-50=147

**This handles capital, number and punctuation, without relying on unicode** (195 bytes + 2 bytes (for `-pl`) - 50 bonus)

```
~s/([A-Z])/|$1/g,~s/(\d)/#$1/g,tr/1-90/a-ij/;for$i(1,2,4){map{for$j(1,8){$s.=index(" a,b'k;l^cif/msp_e:h*o!r_djg_ntq|_?_-u(v_____x____._)z\"___w_#y",l$
"}$_=$s
```

With indentation:

```
~s/([A-Z])/|$1/g,
~s/(\d)/#$1/g,
tr/1-90/a-ij/;
for$i(1,2,4){
  map{
    for$j(1,8){
     $s.=index(" a,b'k;l^cif/msp_e:h*o!r_djg_ntq|_?_-u(v_____x____._)z\"___w_#y",lc($_))&$j*$i?o:_
    }
   $s.=_
  }split//;
  $s.="
"}
$_=$s
```

Sample output

```
perl -pl brail.pl
Hello, 99!
___o__o__o__o__o_________o__o__o__o____
___oo__o_o__o___o_o______o_o___o_o__oo_
_o_______o__o__o________oo____oo____o__
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6 - <strike>282</strike> <strike>309</strike> <strike>297</strike> <strike>283</strike> 270 - 50 = <strike>232</strike> <strike>259</strike> <strike>233</strike> 220 bytes

This would be shorter, but checking for capital letters *hurt*.

```
f=_=>{z='toLowerCase';k=(a,b)=>a%b>~-b/2?1:0;t=(a,b)=>k(a,b)+`${k(a,b/2)} `;b=c=d='';for(v of _){v==v[z]()?0:(b+=0,c+=0,v=v[z](d+=1));$=` ,'-";9015283467@./+^_>#i[s!jwt)a*kue:ozb<lvh\\r(c%mxd?nyf$p&g]q=`.search(v);b+=t($,64);c+=t($,16);d+=t($,4)}alert(`${b}
${c}
${d}`)}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to mbomb007 for saving me two bytes - unfortunately, I found that a little bit of previous golfing had ruined everything, so I had to add 27 characters back in.

**EDIT:** Aaand 12 bytes saved by moving the spaces.

**EDIT:** Realized it was silly to output as characters, and saved quite a few bytes. I also saved a few characters by swapping k=(a,b)=>a%(2*b)>b-1?1:0 for k=(a,b)=>a%b>~-b/2?1:0.

Comment: Maybe it'd be shorter to assign `string.toLowerCase` to a variable?

Comment: Numbers should be two letters (eg. 3=⠼⠉): the number prefix (⠼) and ciphers are converted to the equivalent letter (3=c=⠉). `1-9-->a-i` and `0-->j`

Comment: I've seen different charts - that wasn't the case on the one I checked.

Comment: And I just realized I used the ASCII Braille encoding rather than an actual Ascii chart. So this is disqualified anyway.