# Open the browser to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Tags: code-golf, internet, browser

Your job is to open a browser window **of the default browser** to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Your code must open the browser itself, and cannot rely on an open one.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

---

> Moderator note: A large number of answers to this challenge use the URLs http://ppcg.lol or http://ppcg.ga. These URLs did direct to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com at the time, but have since expired. By [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833), they have been allowed to stay, with the note that they are currently invalid.

Comment: Are URL shorteners allowed?

Comment: @isaacg I'm assuming "yes", since the OP used `ppcg.lol` themselves in a now deleted answer.

Comment: @issacg Yes, it is allowed.

Comment: Is it allowed to run JavaScript in the default browser to open a window?

Comment: @Mwr247 No, it is not.

Comment: You should add clarifications/restrictions to the question itself, since comments are not guaranteed to stick around forever.

Comment: This question has received 20 votes (according to my reputation tab) that add up to 2. There must be a lot of controversy.

Comment: Your spec is minimal, which led to alot of uncertainty over what is allowed to accomplish the task. Additionally, some probably consider it a trivial task. Still, you're in the positive ;)

Comment: Are you banning the language JavaScript?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 No, the restriction is to prevent running code in an already-open browser, which is a loophole that would trivialize the challenge. A better rule would be that the code must work without any browser processes open.

Comment: I am voting to close as unclear because there have been too many answers trying to exploit the only partially-closed loophole of running code in a browser process. The extremely minimal spec leaves too much room for abuse.

Comment: I'm assuming buying an even smaller domain to use is a loophole?

Comment: @Quill Nope, because other people can use it too. Feel free to do it!

Comment: Dear close-voters: there is a lot of controversy over this question. According to reputation changes, I have receive >20 down votes. However, there is a positive difference of 13 with means the community is generally acceptant of question.

Comment: Solution in one byte: [`.`](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @CrazyPython That's not entirely true. According to our BDFL, Jeff Attwood, [downvotes are rare.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007) Right now it's at -21/+34. And a positive score is not an argument in favor of leaving a question open, for example [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5) challenge.

Comment: See [vim's gx command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-gx). Works with the cursor over the text `ppcg.lol` in normal mode. Not sure how many byte that would count as.

Comment: @PaulGaborit in what language?

Comment: Notice just as many reopen votes ad close votes before it was closed.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk One visible byte (with some invisible bytes) in `comment` language used here.

Comment: http://ppcg.ga/ should be active soonish.

Comment: @CrazyPython Note that everyone with enough rep to close vote has enough rep to view the upvote/downvote totals. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: Please note that ppcg.ga no longer works, and URL-shorteners are a loophole now, though allowed for this challenge. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11971/34718

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the URL-shortener (ppcg.ga) used in most of the answers no longer works. This means old answers have been invalidated, and new ones using the same thing wouldn't work.

Comment: It seems that none of the shortened links work anymore…

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### GNU Emacs, <del>29</del> <del>27</del> <del>14</del> 33 bytes

```
(eww"codegolf.stackexchange.com")
```

The previous answer with a URL shortener was:

```
(eww"ppcg.ga") ;; 14 bytes
```

However:

> Much like ppcg.lol, ppcg.ga has been unregistered, invalidating this answer. But unlike last time, there is no replacement short url.  (@lyxal)

[EWW](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eww.html) is a browser inside Emacs. The `browse-web` function is an alias for `eww`, and so that makes `eww` the *default browser* in Emacs:

> Your job is to open a browser window of *the default browser* to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Thanks  to  @CoolestVeto, @Jonathan Leech-Pepin and @zyabin101.

Comment: Can you use `www.ppcg.lol` instead of `http://ppcg.lol`?

Comment: @TimmyD No, at first I tried with "www" but the protocol must be supplied (the behavior is different for example with "mailto://"). For user interaction, there is "browse-url-at-point" which prepends "http", but this is longer of course.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `//`, I don't think. (I don't use emacs, but it's generally accepted without the `//`)

Comment: Arguably this could be shortened to `(eww"ppcg.lol")` since`eww` is now the *default browser* for Emacs itself.  (`browse-web` is an alias for `eww` in the menu bar)

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin I didn't know, many thanks.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ PPCG is not something to "ewwww" that, that's code review :P

Comment: Apparently there is http://ppcg.ga. It may save you a byte.

Comment: It says URL shorteners aren't allowed..

Comment: You can use something like `t.ly/-E-J` instead

Answer (score 47):

## [Oration](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Assorted-Programming-Languages/tree/master/oration), 41 bytes

Not winning, but sure was fun.  As of right now, I'm only 1 bytee behind python!

```
I need webbrowser
Now open "http:ppcg.ga"
```

Explanation:

`I need` compiles to `import $1` with `webbrowser` being the module.

`Now` runs the following command from the module as `module.command` with the arguments of anything following.

So this compiles to:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http:ppcg.ga")
```

I do end up needing the `http:` part though, and it can't be shortened.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37724/discussion-on-answer-by-easterly-irk-open-the-browser-to-http-codegolf-stackex).

Comment: I'm almost certain that you can replace `"http://ppcg.lol"` with `"http:ppcg.lol"`. I'm uncertain whether you can remove the space between `open` and `"http:..."`, but try it?

Comment: @Quill Is that from a url shortener, or did you just decide to buy `ppcg.lol` (and how do we know you won't use your powers for evil?)

Comment: @PyRulez I decided to buy the domain, and all the subdomains and main domains are direct DNS level redirects, if you don't believe me, you can use a packet analyser like Charles or even chrome's `chrome://net-internals` to see there's no malicious data being sent.

Comment: @Quill I meant how do we know you won't Rick roll us all at some future point?

Comment: @PyRulez I actually use the shortcut, that would suck for me

Comment: @Quill that depends on how much you like Rick...

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 42):

## Batch, 17 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Mego.

```
start www.ppcg.ga
```

This will open in your default browser if you run it from the windows command line.

I think it'll work in Powershell too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can use `start` instead of `explorer`.

Comment: You can use `start www.ppcg.lol` instead to implicitly have Windows parse it as HTTP. Works in both CMD and PowerShell.

Comment: Also works in Wine on Linux and OSX

Comment: [It gets 1 byte shorter in PowerShell](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76649/52023)

Comment: @Matt Nice! I should really learn more PowerShell.

Comment: Why do you need the `www.`?

Comment: @Blender Because otherwise it tries to find a local program called pccg with the .lol file extension and run it.

Comment: What url shortener did you use?

Comment: @pyrulez Whichever one everyone else was using.

Comment: @PyRulez It's not a URL shortener, technically. Quill bought that domain a while back and set up a DNS redirect.

Comment: @MDXF When I made the comment, it was referring to `ppcg.lol`, which was indeed purchased by Quill.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 26):

## PowerShell, <s>17</s> 16 Bytes

```
saps www.ppcg.lol
```

Using an even shorter domain provided by Milo.

```
saps www.ppcg.ga
```

---

While `start` is a known alias for `Start-Process` there is another one for `saps`. You can see this from `Get-Alias`. It follows the convention for similar `Start-` and `Stop-` cmdlets.

---

As those URLs no longer exist the only way to make this work is to use the horribly inefficient 36 characters for

`saps http:codegolf.stackexchange.com`

At least we can drop the slashes no problem

Answer (score 22):

## Terminal (OSX), <s>20</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
open http:ppcg.ga
```

*Saved 2 thanks to CoolestVeto*

Comment: `open` is an OSX utility, not a bash one; this would be more appropriately called "OSX command line".

Comment: @Skyler Is this incorrect then? http://ss64.com/bash/open.html

Comment: the first line: "Open a file in its default application, using virtual terminal (VT)." If you try to run that on unix, it will tell you "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console", because it's trying to open in a terminal, not in a browser.

Comment: You can get rid of `//`.

Comment: You can save another byte: `open http:ppcg.ga`

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 14):

## MATLAB, <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```
web www.ppcg.lol -browser
```

- `www` is shorter than `http://` and ensures that the address is processed as a URL
- This is shorter using the implicit function call (which casts inputs as strings) rather than the explicit version `web('www.ppcg.lol', '-browser')`.
- If you are on a OS X, this can be simplified to `web ppcg.lol -browser` as MATLAB will automatically append an `http://` (**21 bytes**)

**Alternatives**:

- On windows this can be shortened to (**19 bytes**)

  ```
  !start www.ppcg.lol
  ```
- On OS X (**21 bytes**)

  ```
  !open http://ppcg.lol
  ```
- The following would work in a deployed MATLAB application (**16 bytes**)

  ```
  web www.ppcg.lol
  ```
- If the built-in browser could be used this could be reduced even further as `http` is implied (**12 bytes**)

  ```
  web ppcg.lol
  ```

Comment: OS X is redundant because the built-in `open` command does the same.

Comment: @CrazyPython That's precisely what `!` does in MATLAB, it's the equivalent of `system(command)`. I had it as more of a demonstration of other alternatives that could be executed from within MATLAB. Is that OK?

Comment: Do you need the `www.`?

Comment: @CoolestVeto Sometimes you do sometimes you do not. When using the external browser you do, however the internal browser you do not. If you do not specify it, no browser window will open. If you can get it to work, I'm more than happy to change it!

Comment: @CoolestVeto So I dug a little more and it looks like the `www` is unnecessary only on OS X

Comment: @Suever that should be fine as long as you mark it OS X only.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 13):

## Python, <s>52</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

Shamelessly borrowing that shortened link.

```
from webbrowser import*;open("http:ppcg.ga")
```

Thanks to CrazyPython for -4 bytes, and Sp3000 for a further one.

Edit: shaved 2 more off thanks to CoolestVeto

Edit: thanks to MD XF for registering ppcg.ga and saving another byte

Comment: The former change leaves it exactly the same length. As for the http://, if you leave that out it tries to open a local file called "ppcg.lol", which doesn't exist.

Comment: You don't need `//`.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why that works?

Comment: You can also do this with just command line options `python -m webbrowser -t http:ppcg.lol` which I think counts as 30 chars

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 13):

## [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), 16 bytes

```
Run www.ppcg.lol
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not everybody has _*shudder*_ Google Chrome _*shudder*_ set as their default browser (or installed at all!).

Comment: Not everyone has AHK either...both facts are very shudder worthy

Comment: I was shuddering because I had to type... never mind.

Comment: The challenge spec requires opening PPCG in *the default browser*, which may or may not be Chrome.

Comment: @Dennis fixed...actually saved me some bytes

Comment: Great! Can't you drop the `www.`?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Do you need the space between `Run,` and `www.`?

Comment: You don't need the comma

Comment: Its an either/or comma or space. This also makes it the shortest competing entry so far.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 ಠ__ಠ

Comment: @wizzwizz4 What's wrong with Google Chrome?

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev What isn't? :-)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I use it daily, have no problems with it

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev Let's not start a browser war. (I always win them, whether that's by having a good case or by still standing there talking 6-8 weeks after everybody else left!)

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 10):

## Java 7, 151 bytes

```
class P{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new java.net.URI("http:codegolf.stackexchange.com"));}}
```

Java is not the best language for golfing...
Here's the same program in a more readable format:

```
class P {
    public static void main (String[] a) throws Exception {
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new java.net.URI("http:codegolf.stackexchange.com"));
    }
}
```

Saved 2 bytes by removing `//` in the URI/L<s>, and another byte by switching to `.ga` from `.lol` (indirectly thanks to @Milo)</s>

Comment: [Use interface for shorter code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64713/45941)

Comment: @Mego I could do that, but then it would be Java 8. This is a Java 7 answer. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: [tag:code-golf] specifies that functions are sufficient, you do not have to write a full program. So `void f(){ .... }` would be enough.

Comment: Can static blocks throw exceptions? If yes, use one.

Answer (score 9):

## Bash, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
xdg-open http:ppcg.lol
```

Not as short as some others. `firefox ppcg.lol` is shorter, but it doesn't meet question spec.

Comment: `xdg-open www.ppcg.lol` works for me as well.

Comment: @digital_trauma interesting, it didn't for me. It looked for www.ppcg.lol on the file system. Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Weird. Ubuntu 14.04 for me.  xdg-utils 1.0.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `//`.

Comment: @CoolestVeto Correct.  `xdg-open http:ppcg.lol` also works for me.

Comment: @CoolestVeto @Digital_Trauma that works for me. Still can't get the `www.` version to work. `xdg-open --version` returns `xdg-open 1.1.0 rc3` but interestingly when I try to pass `www.ppcg.lol` I  get an error message about `gvfs-open`. How do I find out which version of xdg-utils I have?

Comment: Why do you need the xdg-?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I'm using bash on Ubuntu 15.10 - `open` doesn't work while `xdg-open` does. See this answer. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76611/49161 If it is run in the Virtual Terminal on OS X it does work, though I don't have a mac so I can't verify.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 8):

## Java 8, <s>115</s> 112 bytes

```
interface P{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new java.net.URI("http:ppcg.ga"));}}
```

Java is not the best language for golfing...
Here's the same program in a more readable format:

```
interface P {
    static void main (String[] a) throws Exception {
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new java.net.URI("http:ppcg.ga"));
    }
}
```

Saved 2 bytes by removing `//` (thanks @CoolestVeto), and another byte by switching to `.ga` from `.lol` (indirect thanks to @Milo)

Comment: You can remove the `//`.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be java.net?

Comment: cant you replace interface with class?

Comment: @MCMastery Yes. However, with an interface, you can save 3 bytes because even though `interface` is longer than `class`, you save more bytes because the `public` modifier is implied.

Comment: @Ryan Whoops. Fail. Yes, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 8):

## [Pylongolf](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/pylongolf), 11 bytes

```
"ppcg.lol"p
```

Pushes ppcg.lol into the stack then `p` opens it.

Comment: Will that open it as a local file, or as a website address?

Comment: And did you just add the changes that allowed this to work?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 As an address.  
Yes, so this does not compete with others, just for fun.

Comment: Lemme guess, freenom?

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript, 34 bytes

```
require('open')('http://ppcg.lol')
```

Uses Node.js

Comment: Do you need `//`?

Comment: If node.js supports ES6: ```require`open``http://ppcg.lol`;``` (added `;` to avoid tripping the formatting)

Comment: Alternatively, does it require a protocol? eg `require('open')('//ppcg.lol')` to save 5 bytes

Comment: @Martijn Shh...

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
SystemOpen@"http://ppcg.lol"
```

Comment: That would be 16 bytes in Mthmtca.

Comment: Do you need `//`?

Comment: @CoolestVeto I think I do.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 5):

## Applescript, 28 bytes

- 3 bytes saved thanks to @CoolestVeto.

```applescript
open location"http:ppcg.lol"
```

Comment: how dare a high-rep user not format their header correctly D:

Comment: @cat actually, I've never been called out on this before - I've always operated on the assumption that bytes is the default for codegolf (and is even explicitly specified in this question), so explicitly respecifying in answers is just redundant information.  Do you know of a meta post about this?

Comment: Well, first and foremost, my comment was messing around -- I only changed it for consistency with all the other answers, and it's *really* insignificant but it bothered me. I'm pretty sure there's no meta post on formatting specifically, and that this format came from the Leaderboard Stack Snippets, but I'm almost certain there's a meta post for Defaults for Scoring Code Golf that says it's bytes unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @cat Yep, I don't think its a big deal either way - I'm certainly not planning on rolling back your edit :).  Scoring by bytes by default is in the [code-golf tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info)

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 4):

## R, 26 bytes

`shell.exec("www.ppcg.lol")`

I don't know of any shorter way to do this in R.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76608/45941). Simply wrapping another answer in a `system`/`fork`/whatever call is a trivial modification.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 4):

## Actionscript 3, 117 bytes

```
package{import flash.display.Sprite;public class A extends Sprite{function A(){navigateToUrl("ppcg.lol","_blank")}}}
```

Like Java, this is not a great golfing language.  Here's the code with formatting:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    
    public class A extends Sprite
    {
        function A()
        {
            navigateToUrl("ppcg.lol", "_blank")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 5, <s>66</s> <s>57</s> 76 bytes

Should work everywhere, but needs that import :(

8 bytes saved with @msh210 comment.

```
use Browser::Open open_browser;open_browser"http:codegolf.stackexchange.com"
```

Also, for funsies :

#### Perl 5 (Windows), <s>34</s> 48 bytes

```
system "start http://codegolf.stackexchange.com"
```

#### Perl 5 (Unix), <s>31</s> 49 bytes

```
system "xdg-open http:codegolf.stackexchange.com"
```

Comment: use `-M` instead of `use` to shave a coupla bytes. (Untested.) Also, I'm guessing you don't need the parens or the `www.`. (Also untested.)

Comment: @msh210 Can't seem to get the -M switch to work apparently on my Mac... (?), but indeed the www as well as the // can be removed. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

## Rebol 2,  <strike>16</strike> 15  bytes

```
browse"ppcg.ga"
```

if you accept an error before opening the page on Linux, no error on Windows

**20 bytes**  without an error

```
browse http:ppcg.lol
```

Comment: Alternative to the first one (although with the same score): `browse #ppcg.lol`

Comment: now with shorter url.(

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 3):

## Factor, <s>38</s> <s>36</s> <s>26</s> 29 bytes

```
[ "http:t.ly/-E-J" open-url ]
```

I didn't know one could golf-off the `//` in the protocol.

Comment: I think you can remove the space between the end-quote and `run-process`, and you can wholly drop `//`.

Comment: @CoolestVeto Thanks! I didn't know the `//` could be left off. As for the space between `"` and `run-process`, dropping that would require a word named `"run-process` to be present in the current vocabulary search path

Comment: @CoolestVeto Factor's like Forth -- highly whitespace dependent

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76621/45941). Simply wrapping another answer in a `system`/`fork`/whatever call is a trivial modification.

Comment: @Mego Okay, well, not that it really matters but I *did* come up with this without seeing that one. But, there is really no other way to run **The default browser** without `xdg-open` in languages which are not equipped with special functions for browsing the web. A C or ASM answer would surely also have to do `system("xdg-open...")`

Comment: @Mego A C or ASM answer on Windows would also just be wrapping the Batch answer: `system("start...")`

Comment: @cat Correct. Such an answer would also be a duplicate.

Comment: @Mego But it's not the same language so how can it be a duplicate? If I just reimplement someone else's sorting algorithm in my very different, much more / less verbose language, is that also a duplicate?

Comment: @cat There is a significant difference between re-implementing an algorithm in a different language and wrapping another submission in a `system`/`fork`/`exec` call.

Comment: Marking this answer as non-competing does not exempt it from being invalid as per [this policy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7987/definitive-policy-about-answers-not-meeting-the-challenge-specification)

Comment: @Mego I didn't know Factor actually had a builtin for this

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 40 bytes

```
browse http://codegolf.stackexchange.com
```

[(Don't) Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@z@pKL@8OFUho6SkwEpfPzk/JTU9PydNr7gkMTk7tSI5IzEvPVUvOT/3/38A)

`ppcg.ga` no longer works, so needed to include the full domain name. But its funny that Red has its own URL data type!

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@z@pKL@8OFUho6SkwCo5PyU1PT8nTa@4JDE5O7UiOSMxLz1VLzk/9/9/AA "Red – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## VBScript, 57 bytes

I used to have lots of fun creating tiny programs in VBScript, back in 2010.

I've remembered this language and used the code on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13401872/2729937

It still works on Windows 7, at least.

```
set S=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
S.run("www.ppcg.ga")
```

This is a bit different from the usual `start www.ppcg.lol`, in the sense that it executes the `www.ppcg.ga` directly, with an implicit `start`.

An alternative way would be `"cmd.exe /C start www.ppcg.ga"`.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 2):

## RFO-BASIC, 22 bytes

```
BROWSE "http:ppcg.lol"
```

Read about RFO-BASIC at [laughton.com](http://laughton.com/basic).

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp,  31 bytes

```
(ext:shell "open http:ppcg.ga")
```

Note: This worked at the time of writing.  The domain `ppcg.ga` has since expired, making this answer no longer valid.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, 84 bytes

```
Sub Main()
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com")
End Sub
```

Comment: You can get this down to 62 bytes by converting this to an immediate window function as `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink"http://codegolf.stackexchange.com`, and you should also probably change the language to be Excel VBA, as this explicitly uses the Excel.Workbook object

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) on MacOS, 19 bytes

```zsh
open http:t.ly/-E-J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/vyA1TyGjpKTAqkQvp1Jf11XX6/9/AA)    (`t.ly` is a URL shortener).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

The features used here postdate the challenge, but that's fine. Code:

```
’…Ò ™³.ÐÏg.´¢’.E
```

You can try the **string** online [here](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZ4oCmw5Ig4oSiwrMuw5DDj2cuwrTCouKAmQ&input=). This basically evaluates to [this batch answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76608/34388).

Uses the **CP1252** encoding.

Comment: How do you count the bytes? Depending which program I use for counting I get from 21 to 34 bytes.

Comment: @sqlab 05AB1E uses the CP1252 encoding.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes  (on OS X)

```
`open http:ppcg.ga`
```

Simple.

Thanks to Daniel for 2 bytes off.

Comment: You can save 2 characters by using backticks instead of `%x`. `open http:ppcg.lol`

Comment: @DanielEvans Great, thanks.  That saves 2 bytes.

Comment: "'open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: @DewiMorgan OS X only.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 33 bytes

```
Process.Start("http://ppcg.lol");
```

Opens the default browser to the web address

Comment: Nope... Replace ``\\`` via `//`.

Comment: not a c# program, just a single line

Comment: Also this needs the `System.Diagnostics` namespace to be added in or `Process` to be fully qualified to work.

Comment: This is not a c# program.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP (OSX), 33 bytes

```
<?php exec("open http:ppcg.lol");
```

## PHP (Windows), 34 bytes

```
<?php exec("start http:ppcg.lol");
```

Comment: "'open' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## VB.NET, <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
Process.Start("http:ppcg.lol")
```

Comment: +10 for `Sub Main()`, and +7 for `End Sub`, which you need in order to run this at least in a VB.NET console program, also you would need to import `System.Diagnostics`.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## Game Maker Studio, 26 bytes

```
url_open('http://ppcg.ga')
```

Comment: This is not a complete program. Anyway, have +1 for using GameMaker Studio xDDDDDD

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Yes it is. No need to use a script or anything - there is a way to run "creation code" in the room settings, which is usually how you would run any GML code for this site. But thanks ;)

Comment: U're right. There's actually no way of posting a complete program since most of the execution is not done by explicit code but GMS internal lifecycle.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Yes, that's why I usually only use the GML code script in the objects and room creation code, none of the drag-and-drop anymore.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Batch, 17 bytes

```
start www.gfa1.tk
```

Comment: You should include the language for this. Also, this is a trivial improvement upon an existing answer, and thus it should have been a comment rather than a separate answer.

Comment: ppgc.ga is working now.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://gfa1.tk longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 44 bytes

```
from webbrowser import*;open('http:ppcg.ga')
```

<s>URL from [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76604#comment187427_76611)</s>
**Edit**: ppcg.ga seems to become more popular now (but it WAS available when I posted this answer).

Ungolfed:

```
from webbrowser import * # Loads everything in the webbrowser module
open("http://ppcg.ga/") # Opens default browser to http://ppcg.ga/
```

---

## Python, 44 bytes

```
from webbrowser import*;open('http:gfa1.tk')
```

URL from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76863/41024)

Ungolfed:

```
from webbrowser import * # Loads everything in the webbrowser module
open("http://gfa1.tk/") # Opens default browser to http://gfa1.tk/
```

---

## Python, 45 bytes

```
from webbrowser import*;open('http:ppcg.lol')
```

Ungolfed:

```
from webbrowser import * # Loads everything in the webbrowser module
open('http://ppcg.lol/') # Opens default browser to http://ppcg.lol/
```

---

Take that, ppcg.lol! (1 byte shorter)

**Note**: I added a separate answer leading to [ppcg.lol](//ppcg.lol), 'cause I've noticed the other sites doesn't work for me in Internet explorer 11, and I saw other users having this problem too.

*Both are non-non-competing* ***(read that right?)***

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, 45 bytes

Requires the `Browser::Open` module.

```
use Browser::Open;open_browser 'http:ppcg.ga'
```

Comment: Do you really need that one whitespace? I can't test this right now.

Comment: Yes, Perl 6 has strict whitespace requirements.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 61 Bytes

```c++
#include <cstdlib>
main(){system("xdg-open http:ppcg.lol");}
```

Just a rip off of the bash solution using system, and it only works on systems using the freedesktop tools. Also shortened by using the short link some kindly provided, otherwise it would be much longer.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 30 Bytes

```
os.execute'start http:ppcg.ga'
```

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## Cheddar, 65 bytes

```
cheddar.internal(cheddar.uid).require("open").c("http://ppcg.ga")
```

Accesses cheddar internals and then calls upon `open` package and calls it with string to PPCG. Make sure you have `open` npm package installed

Comment: Shouldn't this be Cheddar+Open if it requires another package?

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) 7 bytes

```
`∨¤ β`E
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaEiLCIiLCJg4oiowqQgzrJgRSIsIiIsIiJd)

The short dictionary is a neat hidden feature, compressing the codegolf link to `β`

Answer (score 0):

## NodeJS, 53 bytes

```
require('child_process').exec('open http://ppcg.lol')
```

Works on mac.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76611/45941)

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```
import os
os.system("open http:ppcg.ga")
```

- -2 bytes thanks to @Quill.
- -1 byte thanks to @MDXF.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76611/45941)

Comment: @mego how is it a duplicate - It's not even the same language!

Comment: @proudhaskeller See my comments on [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76623/45941)

Comment: @mego on the nominations for moderator you said yo believe in hands-off moderation. I don't see how this is reflected here.

Comment: @proudhaskeller By hands-off moderation, I mean letting the community do all the moderation work that it can, rather than stepping in with mod powers. As I am neither a moderator nor using moderation powers/privileges, this is still hands-off moderation. If you wish to discuss my views on moderation further, I would encourage you to do so with me in [the chatroom created specifically for that purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37289/2016-programming-puzzles-code-golf-moderator-election).

Comment: @Mego I opened a discussion in meta about this issue

Comment: @ZachGates, you can remove turn `http://` into `http:` and it should have the same effect

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](https://dyalog.com), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

-1 byte thanks to MD XF

```
]Open http://ppcg.ga
```

Uses the User Command ][Open](http://docs.dyalog.com/14.1/Dyalog%20APL%20User%20Commands%20Reference%20Guide.pdf#page=49), which is installed with Dyalog.

Comment: Needs you the `//`?

Comment: @CoolestVeto Yes, otherwise you get an error: `* Command Execution Failed: File not found`

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 0):

## C# (Full Class) 89 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://ppcg.ga");}}
```

Not sure that it's possible to write a full class (with the System.Diagnostics reference) any shorter.

Inside main method only without references, 32 bytes:

```
Process.Start("http://ppcg.ga");
```

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org), 47 bytes

```
import browsers
openDefaultBrowser"www.ppcg.ga"
```

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 40 bytes

```python
__import__('webbrowser').open('ppcg.ga')
```

Shorter version of everything else.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score 0):

## VBScript, 47 bytes

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run"http:ppcg.gq"
```

Answer (score 0):

**URL, 58 bytes**

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://codegolf.stackexchange.com
```

In Windows create a file "url.URL", with a code editor put the code.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As it isn't clear whether this works or not, could you provide either instructions for running this, or a link to an online testing environment such as [TryItOnline!](https://tio.run), so that others can verify your answer?

Answer (score -1):

## R, 28 bytes

```
browseURL("http://ppcg.lol")
```

(in `utils` package)

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.lol no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score -1):

## [SX](//github.com/XiKuuKy/SX), 38 bytes

```
的 webbrowser im**;o&('http:ppcg.ga')
```

Save this shell script as `SXexec.sh` to your SX directory:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
N=$1.py;python Main.py $1;wine SXCompiler.exe $N;rm $N;python $N.py;rm $N.py
```

The script features tidying up after execution. To execute the above script, you need to have Wine and Python. Usage is like this:

```
SXexec.sh file
```

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)

Answer (score -1):

### C (gcc), <s>49</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```c
main(){system("start http:ppcg.ga");}
```

It's for Windows.

Comment: Please note that the URL http://ppcg.ga no longer works, and it is recommended you update your answer to a URL that does work, ideally http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. For more information, see the note in the challenge, or [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/66833)